# Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipod-touch

Is there a way to determine the device running an application. I want to distinguish between `iPhone` and `iPod Touch`, if possible.

Comment: Is the UIDeviceHardware class using undocumented and so forbidden libraries?

Comment: Nope, they're documented. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/sysctlbyname.3.html

Comment: There are some pretty good solutions in the thread that contains [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27759550/2079103)

Comment: This question was asked 12 years ago and is still being updated. UIKit dev team and product folks - maybe this is a sign that there's an API you should be adding?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

You can use the [`UIDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/model) class like this:

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
    // it's an iPhone
```

Comment: @jeeva: The code in that link is a compile-time check for Universal apps (apps which are compiled separately for iPhone and iPad).  This code is a runtime check.  Also keep in mind that this question and answer were written long before the iPad ever existed.

Comment: @Adam i agree with you.. you have have written a answer very long back that is nice work .... i told instead of using model you can use  UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad which is given for that purpose only...

Comment: @jeeva, i dont think that is supported in 3.0 OS

Comment: may I suggest unmarking this as the best answer and flagging the one that follows, with the full UIDeviceHardware class code, as the best, please?

Comment: @AnilSivadas: `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` _is_ safe to use in apps that still support iOS < 3.2: it is a macro in `UIDevice.h` specifically written to default to `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone` on such older iOS versions.

Comment: Works great. I would only change to `[deviceType containsString:@"iPhone"]` so that it works in Simulator as well.

Answer (score 279):

This is an update for `UIDeviceHardware.m` from the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1561920/457406).

```
- (NSString *)platformString
{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"])    return @"iPhone 6s";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"])    return @"iPhone 6s Plus";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,4"])    return @"iPhone SE";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod7,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 6G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (Cellular)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad mini 2G (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad mini 2G (Cellular)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,1"])      return @"iPad mini 4 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,2"])      return @"iPad mini 4 (Cellular)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (Cellular)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,3"])      return @"iPad Pro 9.7 inch (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,4"])      return @"iPad Pro 9.7 inch (Cellular)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,7"])      return @"iPad Pro 12.9 inch (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,8"])      return @"iPad Pro 12.9 inch (Cellular)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";

    return platform;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, won't this function result in an infinite loop due to the first line? Who is 'self' here?

Comment: Yes, I rolled back that change

Comment: I've seen a good number of iPad3,2 devices in the wild – they're showing up with roughly 1/3 the frequency of the iPad3,3 devices.

Comment: Why the name iPad-3G? Is that the official name of the new iPad? I think iPad 4G or iPad 3 makes more sense.

Comment: I've updated for latest platforms using this [link](https://gist.github.com/Jaybles/1323251#comment-791121)

Comment: is there a better way to store this bunch of if statements that it does not have to be in the code directly? (for example in an plist file or something like that)

Comment: The name for a cascaded `NSString` comparison yielding `NSString` is `NSDictionary`.The name for defining one without code dependencies is `.plist`.

Comment: Updated list for iPhone 6 and 6 plus is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19584526/1374512

Comment: Please update for iPhone 6/6 Plus. 'iPhone 6 Plus' = 'iPhone7,1', 'iPhone 6' = 'iPhone7,2'.

Comment: FYI - it appears that an updated list is kept here - http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models

Comment: My app which uses `uname` function recently got rejected by app review for non-public API usage but they just didn't name any API in the comment. Is `uname` safe recently?

Comment: what happened to iPad Air 2?

Answer (score 122):

Please feel free to use this class ([gist @ github](https://gist.github.com/1323251))

> CODE REMOVED AND RELOCATED TO
>
> https://gist.github.com/1323251

**UPDATE** (01/14/11)

Obviously, this code is a bit out of date by now, but it can certainly be updated using the code on this thread provided by `Brian Robbins` which includes similar code with updated models. Thanks for the support on this thread.

Comment: Does this work with iPad as well?  I know there would need to be another if statement, but the question is, does the iPad store it's information the same way?  (IE: if ([platformisEqualToString:@"ipad1,1"]) return @"iPad 1G"; )

Thanks for this!

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you. I have not done any iPad development.

Comment: -1 This is totally unreliable. As soon as a new device comes out, this code breaks.  Also, parsing the output of `sysctl` is a stupid idea, especially for something as simple as getting the device model.

Comment: @Dave: The code does not break, it simply returns a slightly less pretty string. Do you have a better method for getting the device model? And by model, I mean more than just "iPhone" or "iPod", but the specific version.

Comment: one thing i don't get is why you're not defining those as class methods, since you're not maintaining any state. Simply replace - (NSString *) by + (NSString *) and you'll save yourself an alloc / release when using it.

Comment: Just added one missing line to `Brian Robbins`'s answer, for the Verizon iPhone 4. Its hardware code should be **iPhone3,2**.

Comment: It think that there's a need to cache those values to not call twenty or more if-then-else every time.

Comment: Every time? You should be able to call this class/method once and obtain the correct value for use throughout the app. Not sure what your objection is, exactly.

Comment: @diwup - I'm not seeing any iPhone3.2 in our access logs.  I am, however, seeing a large number of iPhone3.3 devices.  About 4% of our accesses come from that.  Guessing that's the Verizon phone

Comment: I made an update to add iPhone 3,3 which is the model id in my Verizon iPhone 4. And I can find no reference to iPhone 3,2 anywhere except in pre-Verizon web postings; not sure that device exists...

Comment: when I run this... UIDeviceHardware *h=[[UIDeviceHardware alloc] init];
[self setDeviceModel:[h platformString]];   
[h release]; i receive a warning "Method 'setDevice:' not found" I added this to my header file #import "UIDeviceHardware.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

Comment: @Dutchie432 : I've edited your answer : made the class as a UIDevice category for easiest use, added an enum return type, updated the deprecated call, put the base platform call as private for internal use only. Of course, I've tested that new code to ensure it's still fully functionnal.

Comment: Wow - way to totally re-write my code. That isn't the purpose of editing, so I rolled it back. Edits should never change the content of a post, just its readability. Read More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80513/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-another-users-answer

Comment: Thanks Jay. This code has already been updated several times since it was first posted. First post was Oct 2009, and you can see its been updated as far as `Verizon iPhone 4`

Comment: This line : NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine]; , should be  NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine]; since stringWithCString is deprecated.

Comment: @chpwn : Some news about the iPhone 4S ?

Comment: @Oliver - Added.  It's "iPhone4,1"

Comment: @Mr.Gando - Tested it out. It works, edited the post to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: What about the next generation iPod? Isn't there a new model out?

Comment: My suggestion is to add this pretty simple piece of code as a gist in github, or as a very small open source project. Since Stack Overflow is not suited for this kind of development ;)

Comment: Just checked the gist and I don't think the new iPad (iPad 3) has been included as yet. Anyone know the codes for it?

Comment: This gist is not being actively edited. You will need to update is as you see fit. I have to assume the iPad3 would be `iPad3,1` for the first revision.

Comment: See Updated Branch of the Gist. It covers iPad 3: https://gist.github.com/2238516

Comment: I find http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models quite good as a source of new hardware identifiers

Comment: It's nice that the latest code is available in gist, but the original code should not have been removed. Users shouldn't have to go to an external site to find the complete answer. You should leave the code here, but link to gist with advice that an updated version may be available there.

Answer (score 37):

I use this in my app. Up to date as of December 2012.

```
- (NSString *) platformString {
    // Gets a string with the device model
    size_t size;  
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);  
    char *machine = malloc(size);  
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);  
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
    free(machine); 

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone 4 (CDMA)";    
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (1 Gen)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (2 Gen)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (3 Gen)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (4 Gen)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (5 Gen)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,2"])      return @"iPad 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";

    return platform;
}
```

Comment: it throwing a warning saying "Implicit declaration of function 'sysctlbyname' is invalid in C99" at line sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

Comment: To resolve the 'Implicit declaration of function.. ' warning you need to add t he following:  `#import <sys/sysctl.h>`

Answer (score 34):

**Latest update - February 2023:** Added **iPhone 14**, **iPhone 14 Plus**, **iPhone 14 Pro**, **iPhone 14 Pro Max**, **iPad** (10th generation), **iPad Pro 11"** (4rd generation), **iPad Pro 12,9"** (6th generation), **Apple Watch Series 8**, **Apple Watch Ultra**, **Apple Watch SE** (2nd generation).

**Removed devices that don't support iOS 10**

---

### Swift

(Tested on Swift 5, Swift 4, Swift 3)

The function below returns a **string** with current device name.

```
func userDeviceName() -> String {
    let platform: String = {
        var size = 0
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
        var machine = [CChar](repeating: 0,  count: Int(size))
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
        return String(cString: machine)
    }()

    let deviceMap = [

        // iPhone
        "iPhone5,1": "iPhone 5 (GSM)",
        "iPhone5,2": "iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone5,3": "iPhone 5c (GSM)",
        "iPhone5,4": "iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone6,1": "iPhone 5s (GSM)",
        "iPhone6,2": "iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone7,2": "iPhone 6",
        "iPhone7,1": "iPhone 6 Plus",
        "iPhone8,1": "iPhone 6s",
        "iPhone8,2": "iPhone 6s Plus",
        "iPhone8,4": "iPhone SE",
        "iPhone9,1": "iPhone 7 (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone9,3": "iPhone 7 (GSM)",
        "iPhone9,2": "iPhone 7 Plus (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone9,4": "iPhone 7 Plus (GSM)",
        "iPhone10,1": "iPhone 8 (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone10,4": "iPhone 8 (GSM)",
        "iPhone10,2": "iPhone 8 Plus (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone10,5": "iPhone 8 Plus (GSM)",
        "iPhone10,3": "iPhone X (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone10,6": "iPhone X (GSM)",
        "iPhone11,2": "iPhone XS",
        "iPhone11,6": "iPhone XS Max",
        "iPhone11,8": "iPhone XR",
        "iPhone12,1": "iPhone 11",
        "iPhone12,3": "iPhone 11 Pro",
        "iPhone12,5": "iPhone 11 Pro Max",
        "iPhone12,8": "iPhone SE (2nd generation)",
        "iPhone13,1": "iPhone 12 mini",
        "iPhone13,2": "iPhone 12",
        "iPhone13,3": "iPhone 12 Pro",
        "iPhone13,4": "iPhone 12 Pro Max",
        "iPhone14,4": "iPhone 13 mini",
        "iPhone14,5": "iPhone 13",
        "iPhone14,2": "iPhone 13 Pro",
        "iPhone14,3": "iPhone 13 Pro Max",
        "iPhone14,6": "iPhone SE (3rd generation) (2022)",
        "iPhone14,7": "iPhone 14",
        "iPhone14,8": "iPhone 14 Plus",
        "iPhone15,2": "iPhone 14 Pro",
        "iPhone15,3": "iPhone 14 Pro Max",

        // iPod touch
        "iPod7,1": "iPod Touch (6th generation)",
        "iPod9,1": "iPod Touch (7th generation) (2019)",

        // iPad
        "iPad3,4": "iPad (4th generation) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad3,5": "iPad (4th generation) (GSM)",
        "iPad3,6": "iPad (4th generation) (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPad6,11": "iPad (5th generation) 9.7\" (2017) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad6,12": "iPad (5th generation) 9.7\" (2017) (Cellular)",
        "iPad7,5": "iPad (6th generation) 9.7\" (2018) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad7,6": "iPad (6th generation) 9.7\" (2018) (Cellular)",
        "iPad7,11": "iPad (7th generation) 10.2\" (2019) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad7,12": "iPad (7th generation) 10.2\" (2019) (Cellular)",
        "iPad11,6": "iPad (8th generation) 10.2\" (2020) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad11,7": "iPad (8th generation) 10.2\" (2020) (Cellular)",
        "iPad12,1": "iPad (9th generation) 10.2\" (2021) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad12,2": "iPad (9th generation) 10.2\" (2021) (Cellular)",
        "iPad13,18": "iPad (10th generation) 10.9\" (2022) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad13,19": "iPad (10th generation) 10.9\" (2022) (Cellular)",
        
        // iPad Air
        "iPad4,1": "iPad Air (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad4,2": "iPad Air (Cellular)",
        "iPad4,3": "iPad Air (China)",
        "iPad5,3": "iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad5,4": "iPad Air 2 (Cellular)",
        "iPad11,3": "iPad Air (3rd generation) (2019) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad11,4": "iPad Air (3rd generation) (2019) (Cellular)",
        "iPad13,1": "iPad Air (4th generation) (2020) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad13,2": "iPad Air (4th generation) (2020) (Cellular)",
        "iPad13,16": "iPad Air (5th generation) (2022) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad13,17": "iPad Air (5th generation) (2022) (Cellular)",
        
        // iPad Pro
        "iPad6,3": "iPad Pro 9.7\" (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad6,4": "iPad Pro 9.7\" (Cellular)",
        "iPad6,7": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad6,8": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (Cellular)",
        "iPad7,1": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (2nd generation) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad7,2": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (2nd generation) (Cellular)",
        "iPad7,3": "iPad Pro 10.5\" (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad7,4": "iPad Pro 10.5\" (Cellular)",
        "iPad8,1": "iPad Pro 11\" (2018) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad8,2": "iPad Pro 11\" (2018) (Wi-Fi, 1TB)",
        "iPad8,3": "iPad Pro 11\" (2018) (Cellular)",
        "iPad8,4": "iPad Pro 11\" (2018) (Cellular 1TB)",
        "iPad8,5": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (3rd generation) (2018) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad8,6": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (3rd generation) (2018) (Wi-Fi, 1TB)",
        "iPad8,7": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (3rd generation) (2018) (Cellular)",
        "iPad8,8": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (3rd generation) (2018) (Cellular, 1TB)",
        "iPad8,9": "iPad Pro 11\" (2nd generation) (2020) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad8,10": "iPad Pro 11\" (2nd generation) (2020) (Cellular)",
        "iPad8,11": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (4th generation) (2020) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad8,12": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (4th generation) (2020) (Cellular)",
        "iPad13,4": "iPad Pro 11\" (3nd generation) (2021) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad13,5": "iPad Pro 11\" (3nd generation) (2021) (Cellular US)",
        "iPad13,6": "iPad Pro 11\" (3nd generation) (2021) (Cellular Global)",
        "iPad13,7": "iPad Pro 11\" (3nd generation) (2021) (Cellular China)",
        "iPad13,8": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (5th generation) (2021) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad13,9": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (5th generation) (2021) (Cellular US)",
        "iPad13,10": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (5th generation) (2021) (Cellular Global)",
        "iPad13,11": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (5th generation) (2021) (Cellular China)",
        "iPad14,3": "iPad Pro 11\" (4th generation) (2022) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad14,4": "iPad Pro 11\" (4th generation) (2022) (Cellular)",
        "iPad14,5": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (6th generation) (2022) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad14,6": "iPad Pro 12.9\" (6th generation) (2022) (Cellular)",
        
        // iPad mini
        "iPad4,4": "iPad mini 2 (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad4,5": "iPad mini 2 (Cellular)",
        "iPad4,6": "iPad mini 2 (China)",
        "iPad4,7": "iPad mini 3 (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad4,8": "iPad mini 3 (Cellular)",
        "iPad4,9": "iPad mini 3 (China)",
        "iPad5,1": "iPad mini 4 (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad5,2": "iPad mini 4 (Cellular)",
        "iPad11,1": "iPad mini (5th generation) (2019) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad11,2": "iPad mini (5th generation) (2019) (Cellular)",
        "iPad14,1": "iPad mini (6th generation) (2021) (Wi-Fi)",
        "iPad14,2": "iPad mini (6th generation) (2021) (Cellular)",

        // Apple TV
        "AppleTV2,1": "Apple TV 2G",
        "AppleTV3,1": "Apple TV 3",
        "AppleTV3,2": "Apple TV 3 (2013)",
        "AppleTV5,3": "Apple TV 4",
        "AppleTV6,2": "Apple TV 4K",
        "AppleTV11,1": "Apple TV 4K (2nd generation)",

        // Apple Watch
        "Watch1,1": "Apple Watch (1st generation) (38mm)",
        "Watch1,2": "Apple Watch (1st generation) (42mm)",
        "Watch2,6": "Apple Watch Series 1 (38mm)",
        "Watch2,7": "Apple Watch Series 1 (42mm)",
        "Watch2,3": "Apple Watch Series 2 (38mm)",
        "Watch2,4": "Apple Watch Series 2 (42mm)",
        "Watch3,1": "Apple Watch Series 3 (38mm Cellular)",
        "Watch3,2": "Apple Watch Series 3 (42mm Cellular)",
        "Watch3,3": "Apple Watch Series 3 (38mm)",
        "Watch3,4": "Apple Watch Series 3 (42mm)",
        "Watch4,1": "Apple Watch Series 4 (40mm)",
        "Watch4,2": "Apple Watch Series 4 (44mm)",
        "Watch4,3": "Apple Watch Series 4 (40mm Cellular)",
        "Watch4,4": "Apple Watch Series 4 (44mm Cellular)",
        "Watch5,1": "Apple Watch Series 5 (40mm)",
        "Watch5,2": "Apple Watch Series 5 (44mm)",
        "Watch5,3": "Apple Watch Series 5 (40mm Cellular)",
        "Watch5,4": "Apple Watch Series 5 (44mm Cellular)",
        "Watch6,1": "Apple Watch Series 6 (40mm)",
        "Watch6,2": "Apple Watch Series 6 (44mm)",
        "Watch6,3": "Apple Watch Series 6 (40mm Cellular)",
        "Watch6,4": "Apple Watch Series 6 (44mm Cellular)",
        "Watch5,9": "Apple Watch SE (40mm)",
        "Watch5,10": "Apple Watch SE (44mm)",
        "Watch5,11": "Apple Watch SE (40mm Cellular)",
        "Watch5,12": "Apple Watch SE (44mm Cellular)",
        "Watch6,6": "Apple Watch Series 7 (41mm)",
        "Watch6,7": "Apple Watch Series 7 (45mm)",
        "Watch6,8": "Apple Watch Series 7 (41mm Cellular)",
        "Watch6,9": "Apple Watch Series 7 (45mm Cellular)",
        "Watch6,10": "Apple Watch SE (2nd gen) (40mm)",
        "Watch6,11": "Apple Watch SE (2nd gen) (44mm)",
        "Watch6,12": "Apple Watch SE (2nd gen) (40mm Cellular)",
        "Watch6,13": "Apple Watch SE (2nd gen) (44mm Cellular)",
        "Watch6,14": "Apple Watch Series 8 (41mm)",
        "Watch6,15": "Apple Watch Series 8 (45mm)",
        "Watch6,16": "Apple Watch Series 8 (41mm Cellular)",
        "Watch6,17": "Apple Watch Series 8 (45mm Cellular)",
        "Watch6,18": "Apple Watch Ultra",

        // iMac
        "iMac21,1": "iMac 24\" (M1, 2021)",
        "iMac21,2": "iMac 24\" (M1, 2021)",
        // Mac mini
        "Macmini9,1": "Mac mini (M1, 2020)",
        // MacBook Air
        "MacBookAir10,1": "MacBook Air (M1, Late 2020)",
        // MacBook Pro
        "MacBookPro17,1": "MacBook Pro 13\"  (M1, 2020)",
        "MacBookPro18,3": "MacBook Pro 14\" (M1 Pro, 2021)",
        "MacBookPro18,4": "MacBook Pro 14\" (M1 Max, 2021)",
        "MacBookPro18,1": "MacBook Pro 16\" (M1 Pro, 2021)",
        "MacBookPro18,2": "MacBook Pro 16\" (M1 Max, 2021)",

        // Simulator
        "i386": "Simulator",
        "x86_64": "Simulator",
    ]

    return deviceMap[platform] ?? platform
}
```

You can test it using following code:

```
print("Current device is: ", self.userDeviceName())
```

---

### Objective-C

I also added new devices to the Objective-C code

**Don't forget** to import sys/sysctl.h

```
 #import <sys/sysctl.h>

- (NSString *) userDeviceName {
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *machine = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

free(machine);

NSDictionary *deviceMap = @{
    
    // iPhone
    @"iPhone5,1": @"iPhone 5 (GSM)",
    @"iPhone5,2": @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)",
    @"iPhone5,3": @"iPhone 5c (GSM)",
    @"iPhone5,4": @"iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)",
    @"iPhone6,1": @"iPhone 5s (GSM)",
    @"iPhone6,2": @"iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)",
    @"iPhone7,2": @"iPhone 6",
    @"iPhone7,1": @"iPhone 6 Plus",
    @"iPhone8,1": @"iPhone 6s",
    @"iPhone8,2": @"iPhone 6s Plus",
    @"iPhone8,4": @"iPhone SE",
    @"iPhone9,1": @"iPhone 7 (GSM+CDMA)",
    @"iPhone9,3": @"iPhone 7 (GSM)",
    @"iPhone9,2": @"iPhone 7 Plus (GSM+CDMA)",
    @"iPhone9,4": @"iPhone 7 Plus (GSM)",
    @"iPhone10,1": @"iPhone 8 (GSM+CDMA)",
    @"iPhone10,4": @"iPhone 8 (GSM)",
    @"iPhone10,2": @"iPhone 8 Plus (GSM+CDMA)",
    @"iPhone10,5": @"iPhone 8 Plus (GSM)",
    @"iPhone10,3": @"iPhone X (GSM+CDMA)",
    @"iPhone10,6": @"iPhone X (GSM)",
    @"iPhone11,2": @"iPhone XS",
    @"iPhone11,6": @"iPhone XS Max",
    @"iPhone11,8": @"iPhone XR",
    @"iPhone12,1": @"iPhone 11",
    @"iPhone12,3": @"iPhone 11 Pro",
    @"iPhone12,5": @"iPhone 11 Pro Max",
    @"iPhone12,8": @"iPhone SE (2nd generation) (2020)",
    @"iPhone13,1": @"iPhone 12 mini",
    @"iPhone13,2": @"iPhone 12",
    @"iPhone13,3": @"iPhone 12 Pro",
    @"iPhone13,4": @"iPhone 12 Pro Max",
    @"iPhone14,4": @"iPhone 13 mini",
    @"iPhone14,5": @"iPhone 13",
    @"iPhone14,2": @"iPhone 13 Pro",
    @"iPhone14,3": @"iPhone 13 Pro Max",
    @"iPhone14,6": @"iPhone SE (3rd generation) (2022)",
    @"iPhone14,7": @"iPhone 14",
    @"iPhone14,8": @"iPhone 14 Plus",
    @"iPhone15,2": @"iPhone 14 Pro",
    @"iPhone15,3": @"iPhone 14 Pro Max",

    // iPod touch
    @"iPod7,1": @"iPod Touch (6th generation)",
    @"iPod9,1": @"iPod Touch (7th generation) (2019)",

    // iPad
    @"iPad3,4": @"iPad (4th generation) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad3,5": @"iPad (4th generation) (GSM)",
    @"iPad3,6": @"iPad (4th generation) (GSM+CDMA)",
    @"iPad6,11": @"iPad (5th generation) 9.7\" (2017) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad6,12": @"iPad (5th generation) 9.7\" (2017) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad7,5": @"iPad (6th generation) 9.7\" (2018) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad7,6": @"iPad (6th generation) 9.7\" (2018) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad7,11": @"iPad (7th generation) 10.2\" (2019) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad7,12": @"iPad (7th generation) 10.2\" (2019) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad11,6": @"iPad (8th generation) 10.2\" (2020) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad11,7": @"iPad (8th generation) 10.2\" (2020) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad12,1": @"iPad (9th generation) 10.2\" (2021) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad12,2": @"iPad (9th generation) 10.2\" (2021) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad13,18": @"iPad (10th generation) 10.9\" (2022) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad13,19": @"iPad (10th generation) 10.9\" (2022) (Cellular)",
    
    // iPad Air
    @"iPad4,1": @"iPad Air (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad4,2": @"iPad Air (Cellular)",
    @"iPad4,3": @"iPad Air (China)",
    @"iPad5,3": @"iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad5,4": @"iPad Air 2 (Cellular)",
    @"iPad11,3": @"iPad Air (3rd generation) (2019) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad11,4": @"iPad Air (3rd generation) (2019) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad13,1": @"iPad Air (4th generation) (2020) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad13,2": @"iPad Air (4th generation) (2020) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad13,16": @"iPad Air (5th generation) (2022) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad13,17": @"iPad Air (5th generation) (2022) (Cellular)",
    
    // iPad Pro
    @"iPad6,3": @"iPad Pro 9.7\" (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad6,4": @"iPad Pro 9.7\" (Cellular)",
    @"iPad6,7": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad6,8": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (Cellular)",
    @"iPad7,1": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (2nd generation) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad7,2": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (2nd generation) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad7,3": @"iPad Pro 10.5\" (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad7,4": @"iPad Pro 10.5\" (Cellular)",
    @"iPad8,1": @"iPad Pro 11\" (2018) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad8,2": @"iPad Pro 11\" (2018) (Wi-Fi, 1TB)",
    @"iPad8,3": @"iPad Pro 11\" (2018) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad8,4": @"iPad Pro 11\" (2018) (Cellular 1TB)",
    @"iPad8,5": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (3rd generation) (2018) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad8,6": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (3rd generation) (2018) (Wi-Fi, 1TB)",
    @"iPad8,7": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (3rd generation) (2018) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad8,8": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (3rd generation) (2018) (Cellular, 1TB)",
    @"iPad8,9": @"iPad Pro 11\" (2nd generation) (2020) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad8,10": @"iPad Pro 11\" (2nd generation) (2020) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad8,11": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (4th generation) (2020) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad8,12": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (4th generation) (2020) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad13,4": @"iPad Pro 11\" (3nd generation) (2021) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad13,5": @"iPad Pro 11\" (3nd generation) (2021) (Cellular US)",
    @"iPad13,6": @"iPad Pro 11\" (3nd generation) (2021) (Cellular Global)",
    @"iPad13,7": @"iPad Pro 11\" (3nd generation) (2021) (Cellular China)",
    @"iPad13,8": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (5th generation) (2021) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad13,9": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (5th generation) (2021) (Cellular US)",
    @"iPad13,10": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (5th generation) (2021) (Cellular Global)",
    @"iPad13,11": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (5th generation) (2021) (Cellular China)",
    @"iPad14,3": @"iPad Pro 11\" (4th generation) (2022) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad14,4": @"iPad Pro 11\" (4th generation) (2022) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad14,5": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (6th generation) (2022) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad14,6": @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (6th generation) (2022) (Cellular)",
    
    // iPad mini
    @"iPad4,4": @"iPad mini 2 (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad4,5": @"iPad mini 2 (Cellular)",
    @"iPad4,6": @"iPad mini 2 (China)",
    @"iPad4,7": @"iPad mini 3 (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad4,8": @"iPad mini 3 (Cellular)",
    @"iPad4,9": @"iPad mini 3 (China)",
    @"iPad5,1": @"iPad mini 4 (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad5,2": @"iPad mini 4 (Cellular)",
    @"iPad11,1": @"iPad mini (5th generation) (2019) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad11,2": @"iPad mini (5th generation) (2019) (Cellular)",
    @"iPad14,1": @"iPad mini (6th generation) (2021) (Wi-Fi)",
    @"iPad14,2": @"iPad mini (6th generation) (2021) (Cellular)",

    // Apple TV
    @"AppleTV2,1": @"Apple TV 2G",
    @"AppleTV3,1": @"Apple TV 3",
    @"AppleTV3,2": @"Apple TV 3 (2013)",
    @"AppleTV5,3": @"Apple TV 4",
    @"AppleTV6,2": @"Apple TV 4K",
    @"AppleTV11,1": @"Apple TV 4K (2nd generation)",

    // Apple Watch
    @"Watch1,1": @"Apple Watch (1st generation) (38mm)",
    @"Watch1,2": @"Apple Watch (1st generation) (42mm)",
    @"Watch2,6": @"Apple Watch Series 1 (38mm)",
    @"Watch2,7": @"Apple Watch Series 1 (42mm)",
    @"Watch2,3": @"Apple Watch Series 2 (38mm)",
    @"Watch2,4": @"Apple Watch Series 2 (42mm)",
    @"Watch3,1": @"Apple Watch Series 3 (38mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch3,2": @"Apple Watch Series 3 (42mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch3,3": @"Apple Watch Series 3 (38mm)",
    @"Watch3,4": @"Apple Watch Series 3 (42mm)",
    @"Watch4,1": @"Apple Watch Series 4 (40mm)",
    @"Watch4,2": @"Apple Watch Series 4 (44mm)",
    @"Watch4,3": @"Apple Watch Series 4 (40mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch4,4": @"Apple Watch Series 4 (44mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch5,1": @"Apple Watch Series 5 (40mm)",
    @"Watch5,2": @"Apple Watch Series 5 (44mm)",
    @"Watch5,3": @"Apple Watch Series 5 (40mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch5,4": @"Apple Watch Series 5 (44mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch6,1": @"Apple Watch Series 6 (40mm)",
    @"Watch6,2": @"Apple Watch Series 6 (44mm)",
    @"Watch6,3": @"Apple Watch Series 6 (40mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch6,4": @"Apple Watch Series 6 (44mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch5,9": @"Apple Watch SE (40mm)",
    @"Watch5,10": @"Apple Watch SE (44mm)",
    @"Watch5,11": @"Apple Watch SE (40mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch5,12": @"Apple Watch SE (44mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch6,6": @"Apple Watch Series 7 (41mm)",
    @"Watch6,7": @"Apple Watch Series 7 (45mm)",
    @"Watch6,8": @"Apple Watch Series 7 (41mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch6,9": @"Apple Watch Series 7 (45mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch6,10": @"Apple Watch SE (2nd gen) (40mm)",
    @"Watch6,11": @"Apple Watch SE (2nd gen) (44mm)",
    @"Watch6,12": @"Apple Watch SE (2nd gen) (40mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch6,13": @"Apple Watch SE (2nd gen) (44mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch6,14": @"Apple Watch Series 8 (41mm)",
    @"Watch6,15": @"Apple Watch Series 8 (45mm)",
    @"Watch6,16": @"Apple Watch Series 8 (41mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch6,17": @"Apple Watch Series 8 (45mm Cellular)",
    @"Watch6,18": @"Apple Watch Ultra",

    // iMac
    @"iMac21,1": @"iMac 24\" (M1, 2021)",
    @"iMac21,2": @"iMac 24\" (M1, 2021)",
    // Mac mini
    @"Macmini9,1": @"Mac mini (M1, 2020)",
    // MacBook Air
    @"MacBookAir10,1": @"MacBook Air (M1, Late 2020)",
    // MacBook Pro
    @"MacBookPro17,1": @"MacBook Pro 13\"  (M1, 2020)",
    @"MacBookPro18,3": @"MacBook Pro 14\" (M1 Pro, 2021)",
    @"MacBookPro18,4": @"MacBook Pro 14\" (M1 Max, 2021)",
    @"MacBookPro18,1": @"MacBook Pro 16\" (M1 Pro, 2021)",
    @"MacBookPro18,2": @"MacBook Pro 16\" (M1 Max, 2021)",

    // Simulator
    @"i386": @"Simulator",
    @"x86_64": @"Simulator",
};

return deviceMap[platform] ? deviceMap[platform] : platform;
```

}

You can test it using following code:

```
NSLog(@"Current device is: %@", [self userDeviceName]);
```

Comment: Just to clarify... `iPhone7,2` is the 6 but `iPhone8,1` is the 6S? they reversed for the 6 and 6S?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You can check here: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models

Comment: Any way to check the type of simulator? :)

Comment: This post seems to have the answer to my query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493800/how-to-get-the-iphone-type-from-simulator-ios

Answer (score 27):

```
if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    //Device is ipad 
}else{
    //Device is iphone
}
```

Comment: If you look at the question Rob mentions "I want to distinguish between iPhone and iPod Touch if possible". Your solution does not address this.

Answer (score 14):

Updated platform strings for `iPad Air 2` and `iPad mini 3`:

```
- (NSString *)platformString
{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (Cellular)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad mini 2G (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad mini 2G (Cellular)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad mini 3 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad mini 3 (Cellular)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad mini 3 (China Model)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (Cellular)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,8"])      return @"iPad Pro";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";

    return platform;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

More usable

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

@interface UIDevice(Hardware)

- (NSString *) platform;

- (BOOL)hasRetinaDisplay;

- (BOOL)hasMultitasking;

- (BOOL)hasCamera;

@end

@implementation UIDevice(Hardware)

- (NSString *) platform{
    int mib[2];
size_t len;
char *machine;

mib[0] = CTL_HW;
mib[1] = HW_MACHINE;
sysctl(mib, 2, NULL, &len, NULL, 0);
machine = malloc(len);
sysctl(mib, 2, machine, &len, NULL, 0);

    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    free(machine);
return platform;
}

- (BOOL)hasRetinaDisplay {
    NSString *platform = [self platform];
    BOOL ret = YES;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) {
        ret = NO;
    }
    else
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    ret = NO;
    else 
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    ret = NO;
    else 
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      ret = NO;
    else
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      ret = NO;
    else
        if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      ret = NO;
    return ret;
}

- (BOOL)hasMultitasking {
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) {
        return [self isMultitaskingSupported];
    }
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)hasCamera {
   BOOL ret = NO;
   // check camera availability
   return ret;
}

@end
```

you can reading properties with

```
NSLog(@"platform %@, retita %@, multitasking %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] platform], [[UIDevice currentDevice] hasRetinaDisplay] ? @"YES" : @"NO" , [[UIDevice currentDevice] hasMultitasking] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: Instead of a complicated if/else tree, you can simply check whether `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` is 2 or not (for iOS 5+).

Comment: Does not include a needed "hasVibration" feature.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a minor update with new models:

```
- (NSString *) platformString{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"]) return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"]) return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"]) return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])   return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])   return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])   return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])   return @"iPhone Simulator";
    return platform;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I know an answer has been ticked already, but for future reference, you could always use the device screen size to figure out which device it is like so:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (result.height == 480) {
        // 3.5 inch display - iPhone 4S and below
        NSLog(@"Device is an iPhone 4S or below");
    }

    else if (result.height == 568) {
        // 4 inch display - iPhone 5
        NSLog(@"Device is an iPhone 5/S/C");
    }

    else if (result.height == 667) {
        // 4.7 inch display - iPhone 6
        NSLog(@"Device is an iPhone 6");
    }

    else if (result.height == 736) {
        // 5.5 inch display - iPhone 6 Plus
        NSLog(@"Device is an iPhone 6 Plus");
    }
} 

else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
       // iPad 9.7 or 7.9 inch display.
       NSLog(@"Device is an iPad.");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just adding the iPhone 4S device code to this thread...

The iPhone 4S will return the string @"iPhone4,1".

Comment: I've added this to the most "upped" post

Answer (score 6):

How about this code, if new version was released, you will identifier with the last know device

```
- (NSString *)getModel {
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *model = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", model, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *sDeviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:model encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    free(model);                              
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"i386"])      return @"Simulator";  //iPhone Simulator
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone1,1"]) return @"iPhone1G";   //iPhone 1G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone1,2"]) return @"iPhone3G";   //iPhone 3G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone2,1"]) return @"iPhone3GS";  //iPhone 3GS
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone3,1"]) return @"iPhone3GS";  //iPhone 4 - AT&T
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone3,2"]) return @"iPhone3GS";  //iPhone 4 - Other carrier
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone3,3"]) return @"iPhone4";    //iPhone 4 - Other carrier
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone4,1"]) return @"iPhone4S";   //iPhone 4S
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPod1,1"])   return @"iPod1stGen"; //iPod Touch 1G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPod2,1"])   return @"iPod2ndGen"; //iPod Touch 2G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPod3,1"])   return @"iPod3rdGen"; //iPod Touch 3G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPod4,1"])   return @"iPod4thGen"; //iPod Touch 4G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPad1,1"])   return @"iPadWiFi";   //iPad Wifi
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPad1,2"])   return @"iPad3G";     //iPad 3G
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPad2,1"])   return @"iPad2";      //iPad 2 (WiFi)
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPad2,2"])   return @"iPad2";      //iPad 2 (GSM)
    if ([sDeviceModel isEqual:@"iPad2,3"])   return @"iPad2";      //iPad 2 (CDMA)

    NSString *aux = [[sDeviceModel componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0];

//If a newer version exist
    if ([aux rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location!=NSNotFound) {
        int version = [[aux stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"iPhone" withString:@""] intValue];
        if (version == 3) return @"iPhone4"
        if (version >= 4) return @"iPhone4s";

    }
    if ([aux rangeOfString:@"iPod"].location!=NSNotFound) {
        int version = [[aux stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"iPod" withString:@""] intValue];
        if (version >=4) return @"iPod4thGen";
    }
    if ([aux rangeOfString:@"iPad"].location!=NSNotFound) {
        int version = [[aux stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"iPad" withString:@""] intValue];
        if (version ==1) return @"iPad3G";
        if (version >=2) return @"iPad2";
    }
    //If none was found, send the original string
    return sDeviceModel;
}
```

Comment: I don't like what you do. It returns bad references for unknown devices. Good idea, but bad implementation.

Comment: @Oliver What do you suggest? You have to imagine if a new device was released, you can't change the code, and for me it cause a bug.

Comment: How to identify iPhone 5/iPod 5? is @"iPhone5,1" @"iPod5,1" the correct way to use?

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Arash's code, I don't care for my app what model I'm using, I just want to know what kind of device, so, I can test as follows:

```
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            NSLog(@"I'm definitely an iPad");
    } else {
    NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
                if([deviceType rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location!=NSNotFound)
                {
                    NSLog(@"I must be an iPhone");

                } else {
                    NSLog(@"I think I'm an iPod");

                }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the very good answers above, here is what I came up with. This is very similar to @Rodrigo's answer, but addresses @Oliver's concern from the comment on that answer. This also provides the option of including the model string in the output string.

```
+ (NSString *) deviceModel {
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *model = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", model, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *deviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:model encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    free(model);      

    return deviceModel;
}

+ (NSString *) deviceName {
    NSString *deviceModel = [DeviceGateway deviceModel];                    

    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"i386"])      return @"Simulator";  //iPhone Simulator
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone1,1"]) return @"iPhone1G";   //iPhone 1G
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone1,2"]) return @"iPhone3G";   //iPhone 3G
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone2,1"]) return @"iPhone3GS";  //iPhone 3GS
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone3,1"]) return @"iPhone4";    //iPhone 4 - AT&T
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone3,2"]) return @"iPhone4";    //iPhone 4 - Other carrier
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone3,3"]) return @"iPhone4";    //iPhone 4 - Other carrier
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPhone4,1"]) return @"iPhone4S";   //iPhone 4S
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPod1,1"])   return @"iPod1stGen"; //iPod Touch 1G
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPod2,1"])   return @"iPod2ndGen"; //iPod Touch 2G
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPod3,1"])   return @"iPod3rdGen"; //iPod Touch 3G
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPod4,1"])   return @"iPod4thGen"; //iPod Touch 4G
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPad1,1"])   return @"iPadWiFi";   //iPad Wifi
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPad1,2"])   return @"iPad3G";     //iPad 3G
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPad2,1"])   return @"iPad2";      //iPad 2 (WiFi)
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPad2,2"])   return @"iPad2";      //iPad 2 (GSM)
    if ([deviceModel isEqual:@"iPad2,3"])   return @"iPad2";      //iPad 2 (CDMA)

    NSString *aux = [[deviceModel componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0];

    //If a newer version exists
    if ([aux rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location != NSNotFound) {
        int version = [[aux stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"iPhone" withString:@""] intValue];
        if (version == 3) return @"iPhone4";
        if (version == 4) return @"iPhone4s";
        return @"Newer iPhone";
    }
    if ([aux rangeOfString:@"iPod"].location != NSNotFound) {
        int version = [[aux stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"iPod" withString:@""] intValue];
        if (version == 4) return @"iPod4thGen";
        return @"Newer iPod";
    }
    if ([aux rangeOfString:@"iPad"].location != NSNotFound) {
        int version = [[aux stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"iPad" withString:@""] intValue];
        if (version == 1) return @"iPad3G";
        if (version == 2) return @"iPad2";
        return @"Newer iPad";
    }

    //If none was found, send the original string
    return deviceModel;
}

+ (NSString *) deviceNameWithDeviceModel:(BOOL)shouldIncludeDeviceModel {
    if (shouldIncludeDeviceModel) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", [DeviceGateway deviceName], [DeviceGateway deviceModel]];
    }

    return [DeviceGateway deviceName];
}
```

Comment: Can we use it for an AppStore application ? is this code using private API (sysctlbyname) ? Tx for your help

Comment: No use of private APIs here. This has passed automated validation in XCode.

Comment: Where do you get DeviceGateway from?

Comment: DeviceGateway is the name of the class whose static methods are shown. So the line you are asking about it just invoking the other static method in the quoted code. Feel free to name the class whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 5):

There's a pretty mature library (by me) for that called [SDVersion](http://github.com/sebyddd/SDVersion).
You can check for running device's model, screen size and many other parameters. It also supports OSX.

Example:

```
      // Check for device model
      if ([SDVersion deviceVersion] == iPhone6)
           NSLog(@"You got the iPhone 6. Sweet !");
      else if ([SDVersion deviceVersion] == iPhone6Plus)
           NSLog(@"iPhone 6 Plus? Bigger is better!");
      else if ([SDVersion deviceVersion] == iPadAir2)
           NSLog(@"You own an iPad Air 2 !");

      // Check for device screen size
      if ([SDVersion deviceSize] == Screen4inch)
           NSLog(@"Your screen is 4 inches");
```

Comment: how to use in swift ?

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#import <sys/utsname.h> 

NSString *iPhone = [self iPhoneVersion]; 

-(NSString*)iPhoneVersion
{
   NSString *platform;
   struct utsname systemInfo;
   uname(&systemInfo);
   platform = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"VerizoniPhone 4";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (Cellular)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"])      return @"iPad Air";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini 2G (WiFi)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini 2G (Cellular)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"])      return @"iPad Mini 2G";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (WiFi)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (Cellular)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (China)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (WiFi)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (Cellular)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV2,1"])   return @"Apple TV 2G";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV3,1"])   return @"Apple TV 3";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV3,2"])   return @"Apple TV 3 (2013)";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
   if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
   return platform;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I took it a bit further and converted the big "isEqualToString" block into a classification of bit masks for the device type, the generation, and that other qualifier after the comma (I'm calling it the sub generation).  It is wrapped in a class with a singleton call SGPlatform which avoids a lot of repetitive string operations. Code is available https://github.com/danloughney/spookyGroup

The class lets you do things like this:

```
if ([SGPlatform iPad] && [SGPlatform generation] > 3) {
    // set for high performance
}
```

and

```
switch ([SGPlatform deviceMask]) {
case DEVICE_IPHONE:
    break;
case DEVICE_IPAD:
    break;
case DEVICE_IPAD_MINI:
    break;
}
```

The classification of the devices is in the platformBits method.  That method should be very familiar to the readers of this thread.  I have classified the devices by their type and generation because I'm mostly interested in the overall performance, but the source can be tweaked to provide any classification that you are interested in, retina screen, networking capabilities, etc..

Answer (score 3):

Below mentioned code snippet should help :

```
 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
   // iPhone device
 }
 else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
   // iPad device
 }
 else {
  // Other device i.e. iPod
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)deviceiPhoneOriPod
  {
    NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    if([deviceType rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location!=NSNotFound)
      return YES;
    else
      return NO;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dutchie432` and `Brian Robbins` have provided great solutions. But there's still one model missing, the **Verizon iPhone 4**. Here's the missing line.

```
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return @"iPhone 4"; //Verizon
```

Comment: Interestingly, it seems like there is now an iPhone3,3?

Comment: @makdad Yes. Actually some Verizon iPhone 4 turned out to be 3,3.

Comment: Anyone know the identifier for the iPhone 4S yet?

Answer (score 1):

I like Erica Sadun's stuff. She includes AppleTV devices and others you might not think of.

https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-Hardware.h

Answer (score 1):

The possible vales of

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
```

are `iPod touch`, `iPhone`, `iPhone Simulator`, `iPad`, `iPad Simulator`

If you want to know which hardware `iOS` is ruining on like `iPhone3`, `iPhone4`, `iPhone5` etc below is the code for that

---

**NOTE:** The below code may not contain all device's string, I'm with other guys are maintaining the same code on **GitHub** so please take the latest code from there

**Objective-C** : [GitHub/DeviceUtil](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/DeviceUtil)

**Swift** : [GitHub/DeviceGuru](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/DeviceGuru)

---

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

- (NSString*)hardwareDescription {
    NSString *hardware = [self hardwareString];
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) return @"iPhone 2G";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"]) return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"]) return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"]) return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"]) return @"iPhone 5";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"]) return @"iPodTouch 1G";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"]) return @"iPodTouch 2G";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"]) return @"iPad";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"]) return @"iPad Mini";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"]) return @"iPad Air WIFI";
    //there are lots of other strings too, checkout the github repo
    //link is given at the top of this answer

    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"i386"]) return @"Simulator";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"x86_64"]) return @"Simulator";

    return nil;
}

- (NSString*)hardwareString {
    size_t size = 100;
    char *hw_machine = malloc(size);
    int name[] = {CTL_HW,HW_MACHINE};
    sysctl(name, 2, hw_machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *hardware = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:hw_machine];
    free(hw_machine);
    return hardware;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer in Swift 3,

```
struct DeviceInformation {
    // UIDevice.current.model's value is "iPhone" or "iPad"，which does not include details; the following "model" is detailed, such as, iPhone7,1 is actually iPhone 6 plus
    static let model: String = {
        var size = 0
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
        var machine = [CChar](repeating: 0,  count: Int(size))
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
        return String(cString: machine)
    }()

    static let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString ?? ""
    static let idForAdService = ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier.uuidString

    static func diviceTypeReadableName() -> String {
        switch model {
        case "iPhone1,1":   return "iPhone 1G"
        case "iPhone1,2":   return "iPhone 3G"
        case "iPhone2,1":   return "iPhone 3GS"
        case "iPhone3,1":   return "iPhone 4"
        case "iPhone3,3":   return "iPhone 4 (Verizon)"
        case "iPhone4,1":   return "iPhone 4S"
        case "iPhone5,1":   return "iPhone 5 (GSM)"
        case "iPhone5,2":   return "iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)"
        case "iPhone5,3":   return "iPhone 5c (GSM)"
        case "iPhone5,4":   return "iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)"
        case "iPhone6,1":   return "iPhone 5s (GSM)"
        case "iPhone6,2":   return "iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)"
        case "iPhone7,2":   return "iPhone 6"
        case "iPhone7,1":   return "iPhone 6 Plus"
        case "iPhone8,1":   return "iPhone 6s"
        case "iPhone8,2":   return "iPhone 6s Plus"
        case "iPhone8,4":   return "iPhone SE"
        case "iPhone9,1":   return "iPhone 7"
        case "iPhone9,3":   return "iPhone 7"
        case "iPhone9,2":   return "iPhone 7 Plus"
        case "iPhone9,4":   return "iPhone 7 Plus"
        case "iPod1,1":     return "iPod Touch 1G"
        case "iPod2,1":     return "iPod Touch 2G"
        case "iPod3,1":     return "iPod Touch 3G"
        case "iPod4,1":     return "iPod Touch 4G"
        case "iPod5,1":     return "iPod Touch 5G"
        case "iPod7,1":     return "iPod Touch 6G"
        case "iPad1,1":     return "iPad 1G"
        case "iPad2,1":     return "iPad 2 (Wi-Fi)"
        case "iPad2,2":     return "iPad 2 (GSM)"
        case "iPad2,3":     return "iPad 2 (CDMA)"
        case "iPad2,4":     return "iPad 2 (Wi-Fi)"
        case "iPad2,5":     return "iPad Mini (Wi-Fi)"
        case "iPad2,6":     return "iPad Mini (GSM)"
        case "iPad2,7":     return "iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)"
        case "iPad3,1":     return "iPad 3 (Wi-Fi)"
        case "iPad3,2":     return "iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)"
        case "iPad3,3":     return "iPad 3 (GSM)"
        case "iPad3,4":     return "iPad 4 (Wi-Fi)"
        case "iPad3,5":     return "iPad 4 (GSM)"
        case "iPad3,6":     return "iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)"
        case "iPad4,1":     return "iPad Air (Wi-Fi)"
        case "iPad4,2":     return "iPad Air (Cellular)"
        case "iPad4,3":     return "iPad Air (China)"
        case "iPad4,4":     return "iPad Mini 2G (Wi-Fi)"
        case "iPad4,5":     return "iPad Mini 2G (Cellular)"
        case "iPad4,6":     return "iPad Mini 2G (China)"
        case "iPad4,7":     return "iPad Mini 3 (Wi-Fi)"
        case "iPad4,8":     return "iPad Mini 3 (Cellular)"
        case "iPad4,9":     return "iPad Mini 3 (China)"
        case "iPad5,1":     return "iPad Mini 4 (Wi-Fi)"
        case "iPad5,2":     return "iPad Mini 4 (Cellular)"
        case "iPad5,3":     return "iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)"
        case "iPad5,4":     return "iPad Air 2 (Cellular)"
        case "iPad6,3":     return "iPad Pro 9.7' (Wi-Fi)"
        case "iPad6,4":     return "iPad Pro 9.7' (Cellular)"
        case "iPad6,7":     return "iPad Pro 12.9' (Wi-Fi)"
        case "iPad6,8":     return "iPad Pro 12.9' (Cellular)"
        case "AppleTV2,1":  return "Apple TV 2G"
        case "AppleTV3,1":  return "Apple TV 3"
        case "AppleTV3,2":  return "Apple TV 3 (2013)"
        case "AppleTV5,3":  return "Apple TV 4"
        case "Watch1,1":    return "Apple Watch Series 1 (38mm, S1)"
        case "Watch1,2":    return "Apple Watch Series 1 (42mm, S1)"
        case "Watch2,6":    return "Apple Watch Series 1 (38mm, S1P)"
        case "Watch2,7":    return "Apple Watch Series 1 (42mm, S1P)"
        case "Watch2,3":    return "Apple Watch Series 2 (38mm, S2)"
        case "Watch2,4":    return "Apple Watch Series 2 (42mm, S2)"
        case "i386":        return "Simulator"
        case "x86_64":      return "Simulator"

        default:
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple comparison I always like macro:

```
#define IS_IPOD [[UIDevice currentDevice].model containsString:@"iPod"]
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

It's simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that to retrieve the front and enclosure color of the device there's a private API:

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([device.systemVersion hasPrefix:@"7"] ? @"_deviceInfoForKey:" :  @"deviceInfoForKey:");
if ([device respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    NSLog(@"DeviceColor: %@ DeviceEnclosureColor: %@", [device performSelector:selector withObject:@"DeviceColor"], [device performSelector:selector withObject:@"DeviceEnclosureColor"]);
}
```

I've blogged about this and provide a sample app:

http://www.futuretap.com/blog/device-colors/

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *deviceType = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];
```

I can assure that the above suggested one will work in iOS 7 and above. I believe it will work in iOS 6 too. But am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [GBDeviceInfo](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBDeviceInfo) on GitHub, also available via CocoaPods. It provides simple API for detecting  various properties with support of all latest devices:

- Device family

`[GBDeviceInfo deviceDetails].family == GBDeviceFamilyiPhone;`

- Device model

`[GBDeviceInfo deviceDetails].model == GBDeviceModeliPhone6.`

For more see [Readme](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBDeviceInfo/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

To identifiy iPhone 4S, simply check the following:

```
var isIphone4S: Bool {

    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let proportions = width > height ? width / height : height / width

    return proportions == 1.5 && UIDevice.current.model == "iPhone"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created an extension that lets you to have 3 levels of identification:

1. type of device
2. type of iPhone/iPad by inch
3. model of device

It updates with last iOS devices

[UIDeviceDetector](https://github.com/Rufy86/UIDeviceDetector)

Answer (score -1):

Update platform string.

```
// Created from this thread: https://gist.github.com/Jaybles/1323251

// Apple TV
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV2,1"])   return @"Apple TV 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV3,1"])   return @"Apple TV 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV3,2"])   return @"Apple TV 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV5,3"])   return @"Apple TV 4G";

// Apple Watch
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch1,1"])     return @"Apple Watch";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch1,2"])     return @"Apple Watch";

// iPhone
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return @"iPhone 4 (GSM/2012)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone 4 (CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (Global)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (Global)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (Global)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"])    return @"iPhone 6s";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"])    return @"iPhone 6s Plus";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,4"])    return @"iPhone SE";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,1"])    return @"iPhone 7 (Global)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,3"])    return @"iPhone 7 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,2"])    return @"iPhone 7 Plus (Global)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,4"])    return @"iPhone 7 Plus (GSM)";

// iPad
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad 1";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 (Mid 2012)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3 (CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4 (Global)";

// iPad Air
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"])      return @"iPad Air (China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (Cellular)";

// iPad Mini
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (Global)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,1"])      return @"iPad Mini 4 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,2"])      return @"iPad Mini 4 (Cellular)";

// iPad Pro
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,3"])      return @"iPad Pro (9.7 inch/WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,4"])      return @"iPad Pro (9.7 inch/Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,7"])      return @"iPad Pro (12.9 inch/WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,8"])      return @"iPad Pro (12.9 inch/Cellular)";

// iPod
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod7,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 6G";

// Simulator
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";
```