# Can i have Facebook deep linking enabled only for iPhone but not to iPad?

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

I have an iPhone app,with no real iPad variation.
I would like to have the Facebook deep liking enabled only in the case the user click a post via iPhone. In cases where is user uses iPad, I would like it to open a regular web page.
Is That possible?

Answer (score 0):

See following post.

there exist a way to find device type. probably you can check device type and than do action accordingly.

[#if check (preprocessor macro) to differentiate between iPhone and iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697165/if-check-between-iphone-and-ipad)

Hope this helps!!