# Differentiate iPhone4 vs. iPodTouch4 in Code

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, iphone-4

I want to programmatically differentiate between iPhone4 and iTouch4. Here is what I have tried :

```
+(BOOL) isIphone4 {
     if ( ![ImagePicker isIpodTouch4] ) {
          return NO;
     }

     if ([UIImagePickerController respondsToSelector:@selector(isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice:)]) {
          if ([UIImagePickerController isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear]) {
               return YES;
          }
     }
     return NO;
}

+(BOOL) isIpodTouch4 {
     if ([UIImagePickerController respondsToSelector:@selector(isCameraDeviceAvailable:)] ) {
          if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]) {
               return YES;
          }
     }
     return NO;
}
```

However, seems like iPod Touch 4 is also passing the test for iPhone4.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar:

[Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

The code example included allows you to tell the exact device.