# Find iPhone Model information

Tags: iphone

While it's not good practise to find out and use this information in your application, is there a way to find what model of iPhone / iPod / iPad you have. For example: 2G/3GS/4G etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
char    deviceString[256];
size_t  size = 255;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
if (size > 255) { size = 255; }
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", deviceString, &size, NULL, 0);
if (strcmp(deviceString,"iPhone1,1") == 0) { etc... }  // 2G
```

1,2 is a 3G,
2,1 is a 3GS,
3,1 is an i4, etc.

Comment: I tried this, `'sysctlbyname' was not declared in this scope`. How do I declare it?

Comment: Add: #include <sys/sysctl.h> to the relevent .h file.

Comment: Thanks. Can you find iPod/Pad the same way?

Comment: iPad1,1  etc.  There are lists of these device names on the web.  Or you can get them off of your own devices.

Comment: Yea I used the list of firmware downloads. They are named the same way! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

I think that this is already answered here: [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk), though I've added a bit to it:

```
- (NSString *) platformString{
NSString *platform = [self platform];
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) return @"iPhone 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"]) return @"iPhone 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"]) return @"iPhone 3GS";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"]) return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])   return @"iPod Touch 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])   return @"iPod Touch 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])   return @"iPod Touch 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])   return @"iPod Touch 4G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])   return @"iPad";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])   return @"iPhone Simulator";
return platform;
```

}

to account for recent additions to the family. You can checkout everyipod.com, for example, [specs for iPhone 4](http://www.everyipod.com/iphone-specs/apple-iphone-4-specs.html) to get platform strings.

Comment: @westsider Does the iPhone 4GS have the platform string `iPhone3,2`?

Comment: I can't say with certainty but web site mentioned above says that iPhone 4S (not GS) has platform string iPhone 4,1. Please see: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/specs/apple-iphone-4s-specs.html HTH.

Answer (score 1):

`-[UIDevice model]`, but I'm not sure if it returns anything more specific than "iPhone" or "iPod Touch".

Answer (score 1):

I thought iTunes/Xcode Organizer did this already for some reason (at least I seem to remember it correctly identifying my old iPod Touch as a 1st gen), that's definitely not the case for my iPhone 3GS. Nor does the iPhone Configuration Utility help.

So I fired up System Profiler to see if the device shows up on the USB list; it does. It also shows the "Product ID" (in my case, 0x1294). I typed that into Google and came up with this:

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Normal_Mode

> Device IDs
>
> It appears that it uses different device IDs:
>
> iPhone - 0x1290
>
> iPod touch - 0x1291
>
> iPhone 3G - 0x1292
>
> iPod touch 2G - 0x1293
>
> iPhone 3GS - 0x1294
>
> iPod touch 3G - 0x1299
>
> iPad - 0x129a
>
> iPhone 4 -
>
> iPod touch 4G - 0x129e
>
> Apple TV 2G -