# Find iPhone Model Information via Browser

Tags: ios, safari

Is it possible to get the model information of an iPhone hitting a web page?  I've looked at the User Agent, but it doesn't seem to have this information encoded within it.  Essentially, I want to [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3991604/1954) but from a browser.

Answer (score 0):

They do have different user agent strings. iPhone 4 is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7
```

You can find the complete list here: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html

Comment: How will an iPhone 3GS running iOS v4 look different from this?