# Accessing iPhone info from SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ipad

I need to fetch device info from iPhone. I went through this link and find out the way to fetch the device platform.

[Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

In UIDeviceHardware it has included sys/types.h and sys/sysctl.h and it has used some methods to access that. So I want to know whether this is accepted in the app store as this uses sys imports and sysctlbyname methods. I want to make sure this approach is correct.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into UIDevice, since UIDeviceHardware seems to be a private API (no info in the documentation).

Generally it's recommended *not* to check for hardware models (e.g. iPhone 3GS / 4G / iPad) but for hardware features that you require (compass, camera, etc.)

Comment: Thanks RupertP. So is there any other class to get iPhone specific information like above. I need to fetch UDID, serial no, IMEI etc. But the UIDevice it only limits to certain. I need to get more data than UIDevice.

Comment: As far as I know, you can not retrieve the serial #, IMEI, etc. without using private API calls. UDID is possible through UIDevice. What would you need all this information for? Is the UDID not enough?

Comment: Thanks. This is for client server communication. Using those I am going to create encrypted identifier which is a requirement for my application. So other than UIDevice is there any way to retrieve device info without using private APIs?