# how to detect mic position on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

iPhone 4 has a mic on bottom-left, iPhone 3GS and earlier had a mic on bottom-right.

How can I detect where is the mic on iPhone? What function does that?

Comment: I think there could be possibility to check if device has front camera. So the algorithm will be simple..if front camera available then mic on bottom-left else bottom-right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use the method as said in the comment to your post. The minute the new iPad or iPod Touch is released with a front facing camera, your application is off.

Why not just use a method like in this post:  [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

The code (if you scroll a bit down) shows how to detect which version of iPod/iPhone/etc is running on.

Comment: Plus Vanya's method breaks already with the latest iPod touch which has a front camera and a microphone on the back.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to detect the specific model of device (e.g. "iPhone2,1", etc.) and do a table look-up from information you determine.  And to future-proof the result, you may also have to have it look up the position of the mic from your web site, where you can keep a table updated with device types as Apple introduces new ones.

Comment: thanks for the answer - I could only approve one of them, but your is also correct, so upvote :)