# iphone click to call from app in OS 4.0 does not prompt for confirmation

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am using the click to call feature in the iPhone App to call a number when the user clicks on a link.

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tel:%@",selectedPhoneNumber]];
```

In iPhone 3Gs this prompts the user "Are you sure you want to call..."

But in iPhone 4 this does not prompt but instead directly makes the call.

Is there any way I can set this to prompt the user in iPhone 4 also?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the device hardware and show an alert if the device is iPhone 4.

See this post: [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk/1561920#1561920)