# how to know is it iphone or ipad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, device

i want to know the user uses the iphone or ipad,if the user uses the iphone i want to open the camera,if he uses the ipad or runs in simulator i want to open the library. how it is possible? 
how to find the details of devices?
how to know current using device by user through xcode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not determine whether there is a camera by looking at the model. This is not future proof - for instance, you would not be supporting the iPad 2's camera.

UIImagePickerController has a special method to determine whether a camera in available:

```
+ (BOOL)isSourceTypeAvailable:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
```

With sourceType being one of

```
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary,
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera,
UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum
```

Comment: I would +1000 if I could. This is the one and only correct solution. But at least I don't have to answer the bug reports from the iPad2 user that can't take photos.

Answer (score 23):

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

if([deviceType isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
{
     //your code
}
.....
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

See this thread -[determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk) .

Answer (score 14):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"]
```

Use the "hasPrefix" so that it works in simulator.

Answer (score 6):

Make use of this to identify devices.

```
// If iPhoneOS is 3.2 or greater then __IPHONE_3_2 will be defined
#ifndef __IPHONE_3_2    

typedef enum {
    UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone,           // iPhone and iPod touch
    UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad,             // iPad
} UIUserInterfaceIdiom;

#define UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone

#endif // ifndef __IPHONE_3_2
```

but if you want to check if camera is available I think you can make use of UIImagePickerController's static method

```
+ (BOOL)isSourceTypeAvailable:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
```

Comment: Note that the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() method is supplied by the system in iOS 3.2 and up.

Answer (score 0):

Working on Vaibhav Tekam's answer, I used this

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;


if([deviceType hasPrefix:@"iPhone"])
{
     //your code
}
```

or

```
 NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

if([deviceType hasPrefix:@"iPad"])
{
     //your code
}
```

etc. 
It's much easier that way as it covers all models.