# Disable the use of SMS feature on an application when running on iPod

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipod

I want to publish an application whose SMS feature to be disabled when running on iPods. I know I have to declare the required capabilities of the device into info.plist, but I wonder if I can ignore the declaration of the SMS capabilities on that file but still being able to use it after detecting the device type in my app.

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
<string>wifi</string>
<!--string>sms</string-->
<string>still-camera</string>
</array>
```

Thanks

Comment: [this link might halp you....][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 3):

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:11111"]]){
    //do stuff for sms
}else{
    NSLog(@"I don't suport sms");
}
```