# How get the news identifier for iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

we found a bug in our program. To identifier the device model, we use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk/1561920#1561920). This work well, but the problem is: how know when exist new device?

I found one solution [in this site](http://www.everyipod.com/). But, there are same official place that show it?

Comment: This is the problem with identifying device models vs. checking for features.  New devices will keep coming out, but if you focus on specific capabilities, you won't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to just use the platform string (and don't translate that to the commercial device name).  For example, use iPhone3,1 and not 'iPhone 4'.   You can always keep a reference that people can use later, but in this way you are always protected with new device updates.