# UIView is not resizing on iPhone 5 Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

I have `UIViewController` with a view that is 320x480. I made autoresizing mask setup for `UIView` to stretch it horizontally and vertically. But when I run it on iPhone 5 simulator there are black space at top and bottom.

Why `UIView` is not resized automatically from 480 to 568 pixels (vertically) to fill the empty space ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add Default-568h@2x.png launch image to your project with 1136x640px resolution.

See here:
[How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Comment: You mean that If I add this Default-568h@2x.png  to my project all UIView's will resize to full IPhone 5 screen ?

Comment: If you have your autoresing masks set correctly, which is almost always true for root UIViewController views loaded from XIBs - Yes, iOS will scale it for you. This is also true when you load your view in code and use [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] as a frame for your root views.