# How to support iPhone5 in cocos2d 2.0

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cocos2d iphone 5 4 inch display support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501292/cocos2d-iphone-5-4-inch-display-support)

I'm new with Cocos 2d. I created new Xcode Project and in `AppDelegate` when i've got:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]
```

that result me 320x480. Should be 320x568. Where is the problem? Where should i make changes to support iPhone5? I see on stackoverflow are duplicated about iPhone5 and Cocos2d but i don't see correct answer for me.

Log from console:

```
2013-01-02 19:19:23.505 XXX[4963:907] cocos2d: surface size: 960x640
```

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or simulator? If simulator, did you set it to be iPhone 5?

Comment: i've got iPhone5 device.

Comment: Do you have a splashscreen for iPhone 5? If not, add `Default-568h@2x.png` as splashscreen and try again.

Comment: Ahhh... i forgot about paste it to Project summary. thanks.

Comment: have you solved the problem?