# Adapting iOS apps to iPhone-5's 4 inch screen

Tags: iphone, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

What do we need to do to migrate pre-iPhone 5 apps to the iPhone 5's 4 inch screen?