# Support new iPhone/iPod Touch 4-inch display with older SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, screen, fullscreen, retina-display

I would like to support full-screen mode on new 4-inch displays as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution). Would that trick work if I build and release the app with older SDK - say iOS 5.x?

Couldn't find an answer in the documentation and simulator is behaving really strange when set to Retina 4-inch and older SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update, Apple will not accept your app if you build it against SDK older then 6.0 and include support for iphone 5.

Comment: I can also confirm this - an app built with older SDK and Default-568h@2x.png was rejected

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a reason to use an outdated SDK. Don't confuse SDK with deployment target. You can still write Apps that require only iOS 3.1.3 or anything you want with the newest iOS SDK.

Comment: I don't have any other reason to drop support for older arm6 devices now

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Default-568h@2x.png to the project, it might just work.