# Iphone 5 screen resolution issue

Tags: iphone, iphone-5

I want to make app for Iphone 5. I read iphone 5 size is little big then 4s. I want to know which size screen mock up i should make? What size of images  like navigation bar , background images etc. can any body help me.

Thanks.

Comment: it's trivial to get the resolution from google. What's your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S.B you can check [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution) to answer most of your questions.

iphone 5 size is in points is 480/568.

So you need to consider this as resolution while design you app.

Comment: iphone 5 screen size is width-320 and height -568 , screen resolution is 640 x 1136 pixel

Comment: @VeeraRaj if the resolution is 640x1136 pixels, then what is the size measured in - demi-pixels?