# Making UI Button with image background scale to iphone size

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uibutton

in one of my views I have a full screen button with an image as a background set with my story board, when running on a four inch screen the image looks fine but on a 3.5 the image is cut off by the lack of screen real estate. Is it possible for the image to re size to fit either screen or a way I can set the image in the code or storyboard for it to look proper on both screen? Thanks[image: The Good one]

[image: The Issue (cut off)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your requirements you have two possible solutions:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter; // Other options too...
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

OR create two different image assets and load via code something like:

```
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
{
     // Load tall image
}
else
{
     // Load short image
}
```

Comment: if i where going with method two how would i load the images for the button

Comment: If you're working with a storyboard which it sounds like you are, drag and drop to make an outlet to your UIImageView (to your view controller's .m file) and then in your `viewDidLoad` method write some code like such, `self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my-tall-image"];`.

Comment: No problem. Good luck w/ your app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,There are many ways for auto resize..
Here is the link that may help you [LINK_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702546/same-xib-for-iphone4-and-iphone5-possible/17145232#17145232)
[LINK_2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)