# iPhone 5 and full canvas width

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, iphone-5, impactjs

Okay, so my iPhone 5 arrived (I live in Australia and am lucky to have it before the US) and the first thing I wanted to do was take full advantage of the **88** pixels of extra width for my 2D platformer using the [Impact JS](http://impactjs.com/) engine.

I cannot get my head around how to actually modify the canvas width.

This is what I was using previously:

`ig.main('#canvas', MyGame, 60, 240, 160, 2);`

Now, I thought it would've been as easy to just increase the **240** by **44** pixels (considering there's **44** pixels on either side in landscape):

`ig.main('#canvas', MyGame, 60, 284, 160, 2);`

However, I'm still seeing **44** pixels black bars on either side after the above code change.

Not sure whether I have to modify any other Impact engine files in order to get this working. I haven't played around with it enough as I'm at work at the moment and shouldn't really be working on my game. I'm sure there's a few other areas I'll have to modify to get this working.

Btw, I'm using [iOSImpact](http://impactjs.com/documentation/ios/overview) and deploying my game directly to my iPhone 5, so there may be files within there that need to be updated as well.

Also I noticed the following properties for detection between mobile devices. I'd need to throw in an `ig.ua.iPhone5` property in here as well.

```
ig.ua.pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

ig.ua.viewport = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
};

ig.ua.screen = {
    width: window.screen.availWidth * pixelRatio,
    height: window.screen.availHeight * pixelRatio
};

ig.ua.iPhone = /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
ig.ua.iPhone4 = (iPhone && pixelRatio == 2);
ig.ua.iPhone5 = ??
ig.ua.iPad = /iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
ig.ua.android = /android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
ig.ua.webos = /hpwos/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
ig.ua.iOS = iPhone || iPad;
ig.ua.mobile = iOS || android || webos;
```

I did a console.log on the following and this is what it returns:

`ig.ua.viewport.width` = 640

`ig.ua.viewport.height` = 960

`ig.ua.screen.width` = 1280

`ig.ua.screen.height` = 1920

I'm a little confused with the above results as well, specifically the ig.ua.viewport.width returning **960**. I would've thought it should be returning **1136**.

Comment: I'm not sure if ig.ua.iPhone5 is defined. `ImpactJS` was written before iPhone 5 arrived. Also, is your level designed for the new dimensions?

Comment: @tipycalFlow It's not. I added that in there because I wasn't sure of the best way to detect for that device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app has to tell the OS that it supports the taller/wider screen. I think this is done [by specifying a startup image of that size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution). Otherwise, you'll be run in compatibility mode and not get to use the full screen

Comment: I saw that post, however I wonder if it applies to `UIWebView` driven applications.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Your UIWebView is still running inside a UIWindow which gets its size just like any other app.

Comment: Not only does iOS have no idea what sort of views your application is going to use when it launches it (ie, when the decision to show borders or not is made) but the framework you link to — iOSImpact — touts that "[it] makes it possible to run Impact games on iOS devices without a UIWebView" and hence doesn't use one.