# How to make application developed on IOS 5 compatible to IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have developed a application in IOS 5 and now i want to make the application compatible to IOS 6. Can any one explain in detail. I would need to set the frames of the UI objects as per the new size of the screen after detecting the device family in case for iPhone 3.4 inch retina or iPhone 4 inch retina. Do I need to set the image also for the two device family?

Also the image Default-568h@2x.png never seems to load. So do i have to add the images for the two devices differently as in case of iPhone and iPad App.

Comment: This is quite a big question. Try testing it to see what may or may not be broken and then ask a more specific question.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution) is a good place to start if you're interested in new device resolution, otherwise this question is too vague

Comment: I don't understand negative votes, people really abuse their power.

Comment: @NiKKi, you need to set different launch images for 4inch and normal iphone.

Comment: @OhhMee - i tried that. I used the image with extension -568h@2x.png for iPhone 5. But its not working out. Do i need to set the image aslo for the different two devices? As in the case of iPhone and iPad app?

Comment: NiKKi, please refer to iOS [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1). Your questions will be answered there.

Comment: NiKKi. You have to provide two same images. -568h.png for nonRetina screen and -568h@2x.png for retina screen. dimensions: lets assume you've prepared an image 100X100 for non retina, now prepare the same image with resolution 200X200 for retina, and add to the name @2x.

Comment: @Nathan - Y do i need to add an image -568h.png for non retina, as iPhone 5 is not available without retina display. For image of 100*100, i have prepared three images. image.png(for non retina), image@2x.png(for retina 3.5 inch) and image-568h@2x.png(for retina 4 inch). Is it not correct?

Comment: @NiKKi If you have some special graphic on some of your XIBs, yes you have to add an extra image. Anyway you have to add new image-568h@2x.png for iphone5. Yes. it's correct.