# UIView height is not right on iPhone 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, cgrect

I am migrating my apps over and on one I use a `UIPickerView`. In the viewDidLoad method I create the picker and set it's y origin to be `self.view.frame.size.height` so that it is off screen. Then I just move it up when needed.

On the iPhone 5 `self.view.frame.size.height` is still returning 480 yet the `UIView` fills the screen correctly.

I've even tried using `CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)` thinking that it may return something different...no dice. Any ideas as to why this maybe occurring.

Comment: Add a 640x1136 pixel Default-568h@2x.png file to your project. Without it, your app will not stretch to full height on the new devices. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12397309/877465).

Comment: Do other views show full screen? did you remember to add an iPhone 5 screenshot to your target?

Comment: Yes I have the new default image in there. I found the issue. My nib has to be set to "iPhone 5 full screen" (I think that's what it's called). I guess that it loads the view size from the nib and doesn't take into account autoResizeMask.

Comment: That should not make any difference, view controller's view gets the size based on where it's being added and not before viewWillAppear: The nib settings is only for presentation within Interface Builder, that's why it's under "simulated metrics".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is because the size you selected in the view's nib will be used until `viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated` method. Then it will take the correct size.

However you can use the following code to have the correct size since `viewDidLoad` is called:

```
CGSize viewSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
viewSize = CGSizeMake(viewSize.width, viewSize.height - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT);
```

`STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT` is 20 but it depends on your app. You may or may not need to add that line.

**EDIT**

The problem with using `mainScreen` bounds is that the frame doesn't change on orientation change. That is the way it is designed. You can work it out with the following:

```
    CGSize viewSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(CURRENT_ORIENTATION)){
        viewSize = CGSizeMake(viewSize.height, viewSize.width - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT);

    } else {
        viewSize = CGSizeMake(viewSize.width, viewSize.height - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT);
    }
```

`CURRENT_ORIENTATION` is `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];`

Answer (score 18):

I've been dealing with the same issue. I tried getting the views frame in `- (void)viewDidLoad` but discovered that it's not updated until `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` gets called.

So try getting the views frame in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` and you should be alright.

Comment: This is great! However, I don't want to keep changing the view every time it's about to appear. It only needs to change once the view is loaded. Hmm ... there must be some other happy middle ground we can find (a different method, p'raps?).

Comment: @JoeD'Andrea I have the same issue, i think that the fastest workaround is to add a isFirstLoad flag to use in the viewWillAppear method.

Comment: @JoeD'Andrea you can also use [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size, that will work

Answer (score 3):

It looks like iOS detects the app is designed for use on iPhone 5 after detecting a Default-568h@2x.png image in your bundle. [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution) has a complete answer outlining the entire process.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. My nib has to be set to "iPhone 5 full screen" (I think that's what it's called). I guess that it loads the view size from the nib and doesn't take into account autoResizeMask.

When the view size in IB is set to "Size: None" the view is not sized right. It has to be set to "Size: Retina 4 Full Screen". Strange.

Comment: but if you do that and run your app on an lets say iphone 4 you will get the incorrect view height cause you get the hight of an iphone 5 view.