# Convert iphone 4 app into iphone 5

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, iphone-5

We have update our application to support both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 screen size. It is working fine in both simulators but when we install it on iPhone 5 device then it behaves like iphone 4 application (Black borders on top and bottom). We have also added Default-568h@2x.png bot not working correctly. We are creating window dynamically.

What we are missing here ? Any ideas ?

Also how to set "Full Screen At Launch" property of UIWindow programmatically ?

Comment: Did you try to set autoresizing mask on UIView?

Comment: No, If we do that then application crashed in iOS 5.0 and 5.1

Comment: Not auto layout, but auto resizing mask

Comment: Yes. autoresizing mask is set for all views.

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538454/uiview-height-is-not-right-on-iphone-5

Comment: and how to set "Full Screen At Launch" property of UIWindow programmatically ?

Comment: What do you mean full screen? hide the status bar?

Comment: Thanks. The link which you are posted is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution that worked

A. In your AppDelegate.m initialize the UIWindow object like this

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]
```

B. In order to manage other UI Elements You can define a macro that provides current frame of the screen be it iPhone 4/iPhone 5

```
#define SCREEN_FRAME [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]
```

Accordingly you can use SCREEN_FRAME width/height properties to adjust other UI elements

Hope this helps.