# how do I update my old apps to iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, ios6, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

My apps use standard Apple controls. Some of them are really simple (UITableView nested in a UIView) and others are UITextView inside a UIScrollView inside a UIView

When I run the apps on my new iPhone 5, they are letterboxed. How do i update them to take advantage of the new iPhone 5 real estate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all to remove the letter boxing, you let xcode know it should work on the iPhone 5 by adding an iPhone5 sized startup image which will be named Default-568h@2x.png

Straight away, your app will work without the letter box.

Then you need to move onto formatting your views to fit. From experience, every UITableView i've had has automatically resized to be longer, but most other views needed some tweaking of the Struts and Springs.

Comment: Amazing. In some of my views, I could use the extra space for my UI elements. Do I need an iPhone 5 view to take advantage of the new real estate?

Comment: I dont understand what your asking. On the iPhone 5 you have more space yes. So if adding more stuff, make sure you code so it doesn't try to fit it onto the older smaller devices.

Comment: So i need a view for iPhone 5 and one for the iPhone 4/4S

Comment: Depends on your views. I've managed with the 1, but have to set different background images in viewDidLoad depending on device.