# iOS 6 APP for iPhone 5 do not start with new resolution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

i want to Update my iPhone Apps. 
I open my project on xcode and open any xib and save this. 
when i start the app on the simulator every works fine, start on my iphone 5 a hat the resolution from iphone 4

any idea?

Comment: This has been answered many times. Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546216/ios-how-do-i-update-my-old-apps-to-iphone-5/12546254#12546254

Comment: i read all the post, but my app will not view on iphone 5

Comment: Did you add the 4" size default image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the "Default-568h@2x.png" launch image to your project.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the "Default-568h@2x.png" launch image to your project.

Comment: I had add the image. On the simulater every works fine but on my iphone it do not work