# How to upgrade my iOS4 app to iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

I have an iOS 4 app in the app store.  I understand on the iPhone 5, the UI will be taller and my app will appear inside a letter box.

I cannot find any documentation about what's necessary to upgrade the app.  Does anyone know wher I can find an "upgrading to iOS6" document / guide?!
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Comment: Have you really not done any updates since iOS 5 was released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on whether you want to use the new features from iOS 5 & 6 or just make your app use the whole screen.
If you just want to whole screen, add a splash screen named "Default-568h@2x.png" to your project.
On iPhone 5, your app will use the whole screen, but make sure you test it with the simulator or an iPhone 5 if you already got one.
If you want to add new features, check out the "What's new" for both iOS 5 & 6 and get started on implementing new features.

Comment: There are also a bunch of changes that might break things (table view section header heights and grouped table backgrounds come to mind), especially if you compile against the iOS 6 SDK (I note that this is not necessary to get the new screen size). I wouldn't release the app without testing that *every screen* still behaves as it should, especially if the app was last released for iOS 4.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'll add a new splash screen and then test test test!