# How to Make application support for ios6 an iphone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, iphone-5

I have a application in the App store, I need to update that application for ios6 and iphone5. What are the steps to be taken to update the exsting app when it is already submitted to the App store ?

I have xcode4.5 installed in mac. If I build the application in iOS 6, will it be supported in iOS 5 ? How should I make a application that supports both iOS 5 and iOS 6 ?

EDIT

```
   public static bool IsTall
    {
        get {
            return UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom
            == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone
            && UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height
            * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale >= 1136;
        }
    }

static UIImage tableViewBackgroundImage = null;
public static UIImage TableViewBackgroundImage
{
    get
    {
        if (tableViewBackgroundImage == null)
            tableViewBackgroundImage = IsTall 
                ? UIImage.FromFile("Images/TableViewBackground-568h@2x.png")
                : UIImage.FromFile("Images/TableViewBackground.png");
        return tableViewBackgroundImage;
    }
}
```

i gopt the above code to make the application for iphone 5.but i idnt know where to put the above code.can anyone use this code,please share with me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution

Answer (score 6):

1. Make sure the **deployment target**  in the summary is set to `5.0` to support devices iOS 5+.
2. Add an image `Default-568h@2x` for the **launch image** of iPhone 5.
3. Check the **auto-resizing** elements in your xib files and storyboard to produce acceptable results both on the 3.5 inch and 4 inch displays (you can check in simulator).

The rest should "just work".

Comment: thanks for the quick reply,so i just nee to set the eploymnet target of coe to 5.0 when i make the archive for releze right?i have that default png for iphone5.but the last thing is very tough to unerstand,how to make the xib to support both iphone and iphone5.is thee any easy way to learn it?

Comment: No - you just have to experiment a bit. Run in 5.1 and 6.0 simulators and compare.