# nib compatible for iPhone 3.5 inch and 4 inch

Tags: iphone

How to create nibs which is compatible for iPhone 3.5 inch and 4 inch screen?
Should I create two nibs? Is there any way to auto align elements when changing iPhone 3.5 inch to 4 inch ?

Comment: Please check if this would help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) videos especially the one titled [Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202). This is a very good introduction to what you can do with auto layouts.