# 3.5 inch or 4 inch design for Apple Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am getting an app developed for Iphone
I need the user experience optimized for 4 inch screens but also support 3.5 inch screens.
Is it better to have the app elements designed (in photoshop psds) for 3.5" or 4"?

I understand that with Xcode we can adapt the 3.5 inch design for 4" but will that affect experience for 4 inch screens? I really want an awesome user experience on the 4" screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nib compatible for iPhone 3.5 inch and 4 inch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636544/nib-compatible-for-iphone-3-5-inch-and-4-inch)

Comment: @TussLászló Disagree. One is asking *how* to use two separate nibs for the different screen sizes, where as this question is asking whether he *should*

Comment: In most applications the images won't differ between 3.5'' and 4''. You will have to add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make 2 designs (in psd's). If the 4" screen is your priority, design first for the 4" display until you're happy about it. Then you can use your 4" designs at adjust it to fit a 3.5" display, for example, if you have a background with a plain color, and some drawings on the top and bottom, you could cut out some space in between.

Remember to use a lot of layers in photoshop, and try to keep them intact. This will help you a lot when you're trying to transform your design from 4" to 3.5".

**Edit**

You could use asset catalogs to set different images to be used on a 3.5 or 4 inch screen.

[Asset Catalog Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would focus on a 4" design. This time next year they won't even be selling a 3.5" iPhone.

Comment: I have an iPhone 4, which is 3.5 inch. I will still be buying apps for it for at least another two years.

Comment: I have an iPhone 4 too, but by the time they come out with their new releases this fall they will make the 3.5" obsolete. Doesn't mean people still won't own them, it means that the any new iPhone purchase will be of a 4" iPhone so the percent of 3.5" screens will just deplete.

Comment: This does not mean that the format should be ignored. That should only happen once the fraction of users with these screens is too small to worry about. That may be a while, especially considering the iPhone 4 will run iOS 7.

Comment: Good point. My only reason for only focusing on the 4" screen was that 3.5" screens are going to be obsolete sooner and if you focus more on the 4" screen you will have a positive impact on more users in the long run.