# iOS 6: Porting iPhone 4 application to iPhone 5

Tags: ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

I want to port an iOS 4 based app to iOS 6. As iPhone 5 screen is enlarged in height, do we need to change the resource (xib/storyboard) files in the project to port it to exactly fit for iPhone 5 screens (or) It works automatically and taken care by iOS 6? Please advise.

Thank you.