# One app for different ios systems

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm a bit confused about how to develop one app for different iphones and ios systems (6.1, 7.1). What I would like to do is: release iphone app for standard devices using 6.1 (I've built my app in Xcode using 6.1 simulator), release this app for 3.5 inches and 4 inches devices. And now I've got a problem... Xcode has different simulators and devices, so my app built for 6.1 ios version works fine but when it is launch for 7.1 there are little differences like: buttons are moved to the right of the screen, webview is shorter etc. How should I build app for 6.1 and 7.1 ios system for 3.5 and 4 inches screens separatly? Should I make different projects for desired ios version and phones?

If anyone could explain this problem to me in easiest way...

Screenshots:

IOS 6
[image]

IOS 7
[image]

This are examples of differences between system version. In this case -> advertisement view.

Comment: i have this same problem and have no idea how to handle this so i make all my apps only available for ios7..looking forward to a well detailed answer

Comment: Take a look at answer with green tick. For you: Make new storyboard and set view for ios7. Then in that story board move and position all controls for ios 7 system. And in AppDelegate file in method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" detect what height of screen do you have and load appropriate storyboard. If you would like to see how to achive this point take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739313/separate-storyboards-for-iphone-5-and-iphone-4s . The solution is discribed below the question. Hope it will help you because it's helped me. Thanks "NewEngland" for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the different devices will have the same functionality, Since ios uses MVC, you could just add another storyboard file for each new device and just change the views.

Comment: I tell me if I understand it right: For diferent iphone screen (3.5 4 inches) I should make seperate storyboards and in AppDelegate method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" apply the right storyboard, right?

Comment: [Heres an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672023/selecting-different-storyboards-based-on-device-type) just instead of using the iPad storyboard file, use the iPhone 3.5 inch storyboard file, or whichever you need to use

Answer (score 0):

you're version of iOS shouldn't matter when it comes to designing the actual layout,  not till iOS 8 anyway,  are you sure your simulator is not in iPad mode on the simulator?  I would look at the xib to make sure you are binding your buttons to the correct places and will show you where the buttons are being placed for each device.

Answer (score -1):

You could drop support for iOS 6 if your users are not requiring it. A very high percentage of people have upgraded to iOS 7 and I imagine once iOS 8 is out, very few will be running 6 anyways.

Can you post screenshots of the differences you are seeing be iOS 6 and 7.

Comment: I've posted example photos

Comment: I could if I would have ios and iPhone 4 but now I have iPhone 3GS.

Comment: I understand you don't have the latest, but who is your target audience? What do they have or use?

Comment: ios6 and ios7, iphone 3gs and more.

Comment: iOS 6 would run horribly on the 3GS and its not supported for iOS 7. At some point you have to stop supporting certain devices/os versions so you can move forward.

Comment: I know it that now ios 7 is the system like 6.0 few years ago but the problem is that I use 3gs as my phone.

Comment: Time to upgrade :-) You are trying to build modern apps for unsupported hardware. Apple lowest phone is the 5 series. 

The real answer is to use auto layout to fix your drawing issues. You could have 3.5 and 4" layouts as suggested by others, but that is extra work that is not needed.

Comment: I'm still thinking about new phone :)