# Working with iphone4 as well as iphone5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

How to create application which will work on iphone4 as well as iphone5? I am trying to understand the hurdles behind it. But I am not able to find any apple doc related to this? What kind of things we need to do for this to make app runs well on iPhone4 as well as iPhone5.

Thank you.

Please refer images bellow!
[image: iphone5]

No if you refer iPhone5 image, you can see black padding on top and bottom. But if you see iPhone4 image there is no padding. I trying to ask that How can we create iPhone application which will run on iPhone4 and iPhone5 as there is height difference in iPhone5. I am trying to create new application which needs to run on both iPhone4 as well as iPhone5. I am using xcode 4.5
[image]

Comment: What should be done in order an application to run on both a Dell and an Asus laptop?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. If you target iOS 6 and just use the latest version of Xcode, you probably won't have to do anything specific to get the app running on both devices.

Comment: Guys its regarding the size difference in iPhone4 and iPhone5. How can I create application using xcode4.5 which will run on iPhone4 as well as iPhone5.

Comment: Yeah I am facing the same issue, Our client want to give support for both iphone4 and iphone5. I am also searching for the best way to do this. May be we have to create two views or two separate xibs for one screen.

Comment: You need two story boards one for iPhone 4 and other for iPhone 5. Search stackoverflow for tons of articles on how to adjust your frame / screen size for iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0):

For the iPhone 5  you will need to support iOS 6.
Dealing with the height differacne can be solved by make the appropriate height.

You can set the autoresize mask or if you wan to support iOS 6 only, autoLayout.