# iPhone 5 size support

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

I have an app developed in an old xcode (lets say 4.2) , yesterday I downloaded Lion and Xcode and I'm trying to give support for the Iphone5 size.
The project doesn't use storyboards .The first thing I tried is in the delegate class load a new ViewController(with .xib 's view at 568 px height) but to my surprise it doesnt get fullscreen in Iphone5.

What makes me believe I need to change something in the project configuration
Any help would be appreciate it.Thank you

This is the delegate code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    IPhone6ViewController *tes = [[IPhone6ViewController alloc]init];
    [self.window addSubview:tes.view];
    //[self.window addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: In particular, pay attention to the default images mentioned in the answers to the above-linked question.

Comment: Thank you Brad.How about this(related topic)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892926/app-crash-with-could-not-instantiate-class-named-nslayoutconstraint