# App not correctly resized on iPhone 5

Tags: ios, autoresize, iphone-5

So I was trying to update my old app to fit the iPhone 5 screen. I followed the instructions on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution). I created a lauch image "Default-568h@2x.png" for the iPhone 5. Tested it on simulator, the app resized automatically to fit the 4-in screen. But when I tested it on my iPhone 5, the app was still letterboxed. When the app launched, the launch image was still the old 3.5-in one, not the 4-in one I added.

I also tried setting the UIViewAutoResizingMask, but still no luck. So the same code works perfectly on simulator, but not on my iPhone 5. Can anyone help?

Any suggestion/comment is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete the app in your iPhone, clean all the targets in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check in your projects "Build Phases" if the picture is in "Copy Bundle Resources"