# Optimized for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, iphone-5

I had checked some apps on iTunes, in supported devices some were showing "Optimized for iPhone 5" & in some it was normal iPhone 5. Is there is differecne between this two.

How iTunes will comes to know whether app is optimized for iphone 5 or not.

My app is running well on iPhone 5 simulator. Is that means my app is optimized for iPhone 5.

Edit: I have not tested my app on device. On simulator bcoz of the small screen size I have to scroll to see the entire screen. How can I optimize my app for iphone 5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optimized for iPhone 5 apps are the one which are utilizing the complete screen area in iPhone 5. Normal apps are still compatible with iPhone 5 with a black strip available on top and bottom of the screen to compensate for extra screen space. You need to include `Default-568h@2x.png` in the code for getting full screen in iPhone 5. And of course you need to handle all the screen changes programmatically for iphone 4 and iphone 5 since iPhone 5 has more height. Without adding `Default-568h@2x.png`  it will show a black strip on top and bottom of the screen in iPhone 5 to show the app with same size as of the app which is available in iPhone 4. For more details please check [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution) In order to see the app in simulator, go to hardware menu -> Device -> select iPhone (Retina - 4 inch) and run your app. Once the simulator is launched like this, you can press `command button + 2 or 3` to make it smaller so that it fits your screen. You dont have to scroll that way. To make it back to the larger view press `command + 1`. The same thing can be changed through window menu -> Scale option.

Answer (score 1):

App optimized for iPhone 5 takes all screen, others have two black bars up and down.

Comment: make sure "4-inch Retina" is selected in the emulator.

Comment: @jan267 - is that mean when I run my app on iPhone5 device, it will show black bars upside down like it shows 1x in iPad. Can't I check on this on simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Run app on iOS simultor, 
In the menu open Hardware > Device > 4-inch retina. If there are no bars, then your app is optimized for iphone 5.

PS: Also try rotating the simulator if you have optimized your app for 4 inch screens. (In case you have such functionality in your app).

Answer (score 0):

Please selected: "Don't use asset catalogs" and then add launch image in Supporting Files.

Naming convention of launch image would be:

- Default-568h@2x.png (640*1136) 4 inch iPhone
- Default@2x.png (640*960) 3.5 inch iPhone Retina display
- Default.png (320*480) 3.5 inch iPhone non-Retina display