# Storyboarding, Interface Builder not loading 568h images

Tags: ios, ios6, autolayout

I have a full screen image called heart.png loaded into an UIImageView that's 320x480. I've created a 640x960 version and named it heart@2x.png. I also created a 640x1136 version and named it heart-568h@2x.png.

I built a 3.5" view in a storyboard with an UIImageView that's 320x480. I'd assume using a 4" screen device will automatically load heart-568h@2x.png but it does not seem to be the case. Do I have to create 2 storyboards for 3.5" and 4" screens?

EDIT

So far everything is being done in IB, no code has been used. Here's an example project I just set up:
[image]

Comment: So to clarify, you have an image view sized with autolayout that you are simply setting an image on it (presumably) with the code: `[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart"];`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  The device will not automatically load the 568 image (other than the launch image) in the way that it differentiates between regular and retina (@2x).  You will have to programmatically check, or use a separate storyboard / NIB.

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(screenSize.height == 568) {
           // ...
        }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully not too off topic, but I have a lot of views with several assets that are designed specifically for the 4" screens. Would it make sense to design two Storyboards, one for 3.5" and one for 4"?

Comment: That's the direction I'm headed... but I'm reluctant to say if it's a best practice or not.

Answer (score 2):

I built my own Custom ImageView Class like this:

```
//  UICustomImageView.h
@interface UICustomImageView : UIImageView
@property (nonatomic) NSString *filename568;
@end

//  UICustomImageView.m
#import "UICustomImageView.h"

@implementation UICustomImageView

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self checkFor568];
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    [self checkFor568];
}

-(void)checkFor568 {
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(screenSize.height == 568) {
            if (self.filename568 != nil)
                self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.filename568];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Use it in Interface Builder like this. (Still name the image Background-568h@2x.png for scaling):

[image: Interface Builder Custom Attributes]

Comment: This is the easiest and painless way to do this via IB! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Search through Stack overflow, I've learned that images do not automatically load images with -568h in the name.