# Xcode 4.5 Uploading a iPhone 5 app only

Tags: ios6, screenshot, app-store-connect, xcode4.5, iphone-5

i have a app built in Xcode 4.5 with 4 inch screen/View controllers i built this app just for iPhone 5 as i sent it off to iTunes connect. once it said upload received it showed "Missing Localized Screenshots" straight away.

how can i fix this i have 5 screenshots for iPhone 5 and thats it, but if i was to put screenshots for 3.5 inch screens the message goes and my app will wait for review but the one problem is when i run it on my iPod all the images/buttons are I'ver off the screen or in a different places please help.

are there any ways around this if so i really would appreciate it if you could let me known.

or do you have to develop a applications for both devices iPhone 5 and iPhone 4 now?

hope this all make sense and you guys understand what i mean thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't about the device, but the version of the OS. You can't target an app just at the iPhone 5. You can can target an app at iOS version 6 which includes 4 inch and 3.5 inch screens.

**Edited to add**

There are many resources about supporting multiple screen sizes in iOS6, one of which is, for example:

[How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Comment: ok so whats the best way to go about this then what should i do ? @Abizern

Comment: There are a whole load of things you can do to support the multiple screen sizes between the 3.5 and 4 inch screens.

Comment: ok my friend but could you point me in the correct direction because i dont have a glue?

Comment: ok whats the quickest way to make all my view controllers 3.5 inchs

Comment: @Abizern Can I limit my app to work only for iPhone5 and pass through app store approval process ?

Comment: Nope. Have a look at the App Store guidelines