# how to create iphone application which is compatible for iphone 4 and 5 screen sizes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, iphone-4, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

I have two sets of images.One set of images  to iphone 4 background images and other set of images to iphone 5.How can I use these two image sets to create my iphone application which wants to be compatible with both screen sizes ?
do I want to check the iphone version and apply images using some coding ?
Hope you can help.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a class extension called `UIDevice`. You can find the source here: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension

I have set up a neat little method which layouts the view according to screen size.
Example:

```
- (void)setupGUI
{  
    UIImage *backgroundImage;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] platformType] == UIDevice5iPhone)
    {
        //4 inch screen
         backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_background-568h@2x"].CGImage scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    }
    else
    {
        //3.5 inch screen

        backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"main_background"] retain];
    }
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
    [backgroundImage release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the splash you can use the suffix `-568h@2x`

For UIImage you can use:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"tryImage"]
```

And you can have `tryImage.png`, `tryImage@2x.png` and `tryImage-568h@2x.png`, but it seems not to be working as we would like.

You can also use a trick like this: https://gist.github.com/3782351

Comment: Thanks for your reply, :) Yes,I have these 3 types of background images(tryImage.png,tryImage@2x.png,tryImage-568h@2x.png).If I'am using ios6 version to create my app,Then When I get a new xib, I am getting a view which has 568 of screen height.So, still do I want to use tryImage.png as default background of that view or do I need to use tryImage-568h@2x.png ?

Comment: I have got a new xib and I have added an imageView which has the same height as its view(568) and I have used tryImage.png as its background image.Is it correct ?