# How to migrate existing iphone application to iphone 5 screen resolution as well?

Tags: iphone, ios6, iphone-5

I have my existing application, I want to migrate these application to iPhone 5 resolution  as well, I tried lot of links regarding these problem, I haven't get clear idea about actually to migrate the application, Please give the idea, regarding these problem.
              I referred following link as well but haven't get clear idea about these problem....
  [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)
From above link I done with splash screen, but the remaining nib ui height not proper, in some screen, above will get more space and in some below space is more, SO how to solve these prob, please help me.

Comment: Do you use IB? If you do build a view for both, check for device before loading an .xib then load for device

Comment: Can we use autosizing property in xib? to solve these problem

Comment: im sure in some cases you can, though unless you built the views completely in code, building a new xib might be the way you want to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you going to support iOS 5 or earlier?  If not, I recommend learning about Autolayout.  With this feature, you can set up constraints that will ensure layouts between the devices appear similar (with just a little more room for your views).

First, read this to learn about the recommended usability recommendations for different devices (scroll down to the "Running on iPhone 5" section): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/TranslateApp/TranslateApp.html

Then, for Autolayout check out this WWDC video:
[Introduction to Auto Layout for iOS and OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=202)