# When will an app be letterboxed in iPhone 5?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-5

In what situations will an app be shown in letterbox on iPhone 5? i.e. What criteria does iPhone 5 use to do this?
What are the steps that one should take to keep that from happening?

Comment: The Related Questions sidebar on this very page has some things you might find useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  I want to know the exact criteria that would cause an app to be letterboxed by iPhone 5.  That's different than wanting to migrate it to iPhone 5.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.  Essentially if you include Default-568h@2x.png in your project, your app won't be letterboxed.  If you exclude, it will.