# How do I test apps created using iPhone 5 screen size in iOS6 simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, iphone-5, iphone-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Although I am using iphone6 simulator, my simulator size is same as the iPhone 4, But I want to test my app in iphone5 screen size. So,how can I test an iphone5 app ? Thank you :)

Comment: Where can I get this iPhone 6 simulator? :) I take it you mean iOS 6? To use the iPhone 5 simulator you have to include `Default-568h@2x.png` in your bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to go to hardware and select iPhone 4in Retina.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the simulator, go to the menu "Hardware" > "Device" and select "iPhone (Retina 4-inch)"

Comment: Haha 8 seconds before me! Damn screen shot slowed me down!

Comment: @RyanPoolos: I'm last, and did not even post the screenshot :p. I did translate from French to English though, lol.

Comment: I was first! Nanananana na! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, *iPhone 6.0 Simulator* means an iPhone Simulator with iOS 6.0. Start the simulator, and go to the *Hardware* menu, choose *iPhone (Retina 4-inch)* to run in an iPhone 5 (with iOS 6.0) simulator.