# Launch image for iPhone applications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

I've a question about the launch image of an iPhone app. Until now in my app's I included two launch app images: Default.png (320 x 480) and Default@2.png(640 x 960), the first one for normal resolution and the second one for high resolution.

The question is that, with the new iPhone 5, the high resolution image should have a size of 640 x 1136? If yes, how this image will be shown in an iPhone4? In the iPhone4 an image of 640 x 1136 size is shown centered? or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include 3 images now

```
320x480 - Default.png
640x960 - Default@2x.png
640x1136 - Default-568h@2x.png
```

-- the one used is based on screensize