# Customizing layout for both 3.5 and 4 inch iPhone screens without use of autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I can't use autolayout due to iOS version incompatibility. But what in case I want some components at the bottom of the screen (maybe with some padding) and also tab bar included. What is a proper approach of doing this?

Comment: You can use CGRect for the view

Comment: What do you mean? THat I have to programically move/resize my view?

Comment: no, you have not to move or resize the view

Comment: Check Out May be it will help you


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating your interface in IB, then you could use the autosizing masks (also referred to as 'springs and struts'), available on the Size Inspector.

[image: Autosizing]

It's less flexible then AutoLayout, so your mileage may vary...