# Convert ios4 app into ios5

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I have already created an app compatible with ios<5. Which already exists at [Workout DJ FREE for Spotify](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/workout-dj-free-for-spotify/id586168732?mt=8)

Now in next version I want this app compatible with ios5 too. For that what do I need to do?

I have planned to go with either of these two options

1. Make separate xib for each screen
2. Create all images with more retina display & name it with @(some)X. Like we do @2x for retina display.

I don't think the 2nd option will work at all, will it?

I'm seeking guidance from the ios5 experts.What should I do? Should I go with either of above two options or there is some other alternative that is standard & best.

Comment: Are you really asking about upgrading an iOS 4 app to run on iOS 5 are you asking about making an app designed for the iPhone 4 or older run well on an iPhone 5?

Comment: @Remear Yes,you are right. My app does run well on ios5 as everybody knows that "iOS 4.x apps are likely 99.99% compatible with iOS 5.x". But I want to set screen layout in a way that ios4 screens also look good on ios5 screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the below tutorial. You will have idea of how to set design for iPhone 4 & 5 compatible.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/working-with-the-iphone-5-display/

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need separate views for the iPhone 5 and <= iPhone 4.

Just add a new Default screen for the iPhone 5 to trigger automatic view sizing to work on the iPhone 5 and make sure all of your Autolayout or resizing masks are correct.

Yes, you'll want to make sure you supply retina graphics so everything looks good on the retina displays in the iPhone 4 and iPhone 5.

Comment: thanks. I have few questions. By "Default screen", do you mean to say startup/splash screen?How to check my all autolayout or resizing masks are correct? How to supply retina display for ios5? Since I'm making my first app compatible with ios5. I appreciate you for bearing my questions.

Comment: You'll want to start by reading through everything at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Comment: To trigger the resizing for the iPhone 5, drop an image into your project folder named Default-568h@2x.png. Here's another guide for this topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution. And here's more info on Autolayout. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/UnderstandingAutolayout.html

Comment: Ok thanks a ton. Will response to your answer soon, after analyzing it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, try googling it. Maybe try checking out this forum article here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1356952

Comment: Thanks @Harrison Howard .But your provided forum url is not for me. I do know very well that "iOS 4.x apps are likely 99.99% compatible with iOS 5.x", but I'm asking about how to set screen layout in a way that ios4 screens also look good on ios5 screen.