# Screen Layout Issues for iPhone-5 large screens

Tags: iphone, layout, splash-screen, statusbar, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

[image: Layout Issue]

As I attached an Image, I've generated view in XIB for iPhone-5 screen size. When I'll run as iPhone-4s retina for iPhone5 screen, but It'll show like this in the simulator for the iPhone-4s screen.

I've done with all size settings auto with screen size attributes.

Actually Not getting to the status-bar issue.
If the screen is not compatible with large screen, then also status-bar should be on top. But why is it so showing in the middle ?

Can anyone tell me the solution for this asap?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the splash Image to your project named **Default-568h@2x.png**

This will show your layout in full screen rather than displaying it in middle.

Answer (score 0):

Set this in App delegate class in Didfinishlaunching method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: In whole Application, I'm getting the same issue. So this is not a feasible solution to hide the status - bar. I am not getting why the application is displayed in the middle. ?

Comment: I don't want to hide status-bar.
So,I have created a Splash screeen for iPhone5 in resources/iphone (640x1136).
Its name must be: Default-568h@2x.png

Problem Solved.

Comment: Ya bro this is right solution...

Answer (score 0):

I have been successful in this earlier.

Write `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];` in AppDelegate and in `.plist` file set property `Statusbar is initially hidden` to `YES`.

Hope this will help you....:)

Comment: In whole Application, I'm getting the same issue. So this is not a feasible solution to hide the status - bar. I am not getting why the application is displayed in the middle. ?

Comment: I don't want to hide status-bar.
So,I have created a Splash screeen for iPhone5 in resources/iphone (640x1136).
Its name must be: Default-568h@2x.png

Problem Solved.

Comment: Yes..and the other way is you put Default images for iphone 4 and 5. Then, check programmatically whether current device is iphone 5 or 4. According to that, you can set image...

Answer (score -1):

You can check device screen compatibility as below:

```
//Device Compatibility
#define g_IS_IPHONE             ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] )
#define g_IS_IPOD               ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"] )
#define g_IS_IPAD               ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPad"] )
#define g_IS_IPHONE_5_SCREEN    [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 1024.0f
#define g_IS_IPHONE_4_SCREEN    [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 480.0f && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 568.0f


if(g_IS_IPHONE_5_SCREEN)
{
    if(g_IS_IPHONE)
        NSLog(@"Hey, this is an iPhone 5 screen!");
    else if(g_IS_IPOD)
        NSLog(@"Hey, this is an iPod 5 screen!");
    else
        NSLog(@"Hey, this is a simulator screen with iPhone 5 screen height!");
}
else if(g_IS_IPHONE_4_SCREEN)
{
    if(g_IS_IPHONE)
        NSLog(@"Hey, this is a lower iPhone screen than 5!");
    else if(g_IS_IPOD)
        NSLog(@"Hey, this is a lower iPod screen than 5!");
    else
        NSLog(@"Hey, this is a lower simulator screen than 5!");
}
else if(g_IS_IPAD){
    NSLog(@"Hey, this is an iPad screen!");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Hey, this is an ipad simulator screen!");
}
```

Cheers!