# How to design single storyboard file that supports all iphone screen sizes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using storyboard and xcode 4.6 for designing Iphone app. I have very complex viewscontrollers and some of the subviews(like scrollview's and autocomplete tablviews) have generated dynamically. When app build for iphone 4 everything works fine. But, when using Iphone(retina-4 inch) simulator, I noticed that there is space at the top and bottom of the screen and also some of the subviews (like scrollviews and autocomplete tableviews ..) misplaced and covering other subviews in that viewcontroller. I tried to search and found some are suggesting to design/load two xib files based on screen size. I have enabled both autoresize masks and autolayout, but still the problem persists.

***How to design a single storyboard file that is feasible for both Iphone-4 and Iphone-5.***

Reference:[How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

**Update attached screenshot**:
Storyboard file

[image]

[image]
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution

Comment: Without more specifics about the view in question, your question seems very much like a duplicate of the question you linked as a reference.

Comment: @Caleb, I will attach a screen shot of the my app. Please have a look and suggest. thanks for reply

Comment: @JordiKroon, I had mentioned that link as Reference in my question. Not duplicate

Answer (score 4):

use the button in the picture below to toggle between retina 4 in and 3.5 inch. use the autosizing tool under the size inspector on the top right to get views to position themselves correctly.

[image: xcode button]

Comment: many of the subviews are generated programmatically. So, above is not possible. thanks for reply

Comment: yeah the only real way to deal with it that i know of then is to pretty much do all your programmatic laying out in the method described in [this questions answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution_). the storyboard cant help you if you are doing programmatic stuff