# Design Screen for 3.5 Inch Display In xib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib

i Design outlet(xib) file for 4.0 Inch Screen Size.Now i want in 3.5 screen size.means working for both size. is it possible ??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221390/how-to-design-single-storyboard-file-that-supports-all-iphone-screen-sizes/15221550#15221550

Comment: the answer applies to xib's as well