# iPhone 5 app won't launch with full resolution despite Default-568h@2x.png

Tags: iphone, ios, screen, resolution, iphone-5

I have done this: [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution) i.e. added the Default-568h@2x.png file.

My app still launches with the black bars top and bottom. It launches with the Default.png launch image, not even the Default@2x.png.

I'm using story board for layout of the screens, not xib. It's a pretty basic series of screens, table view driven.

What the hell have I done wrong?

All the source code is viewable here: https://github.com/scotartt/LatinLookupTool

Comment: Just tested, works OK on Simulator. Try to clean your project, remove app from device/simulator and run again.

Comment: How you added splashScreen ? It is showing in target->summary ? ... Copy those files in to your project folder then add them by right clicking on your project ... remember name should be correct before adding them into project. Then reset your simulator and try again.

Comment: add individual xib for them or use autolayout provided by latest xcode

Comment: Tiger: if you look at the source code you'll see how the files are added.

Comment: pcholberg: thanks, that was exactly it, wanna add that as the answer and I'll vote it as the answer.

Comment: Your projext Works perfectly in simulator. Try adding the launch image  for 4inch retina again in the summary .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the images, and re-adding them along with cleaning the project before rebuild was the answer as suggested by pcholberg and Renjith

Comment: It's amazing what a clean, delete, and re-deploy can do these days. Im honestly surprised sometimes at how much caching is used throughout ios.