# Cocos2d - Default iPhone5 support with -wide / -widehd not working

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I believe now Cocos2D 2.1 and above Support iPhone5 with image extension -widehd.png

I used same but not working in my game. Just searched in cocos2d and found these in CCFileUtils.h

```
- iPhone: ""
- iPhone HD: "-hd"
- iPhone5 : "-wide"
- iPhone5 HD: "-widehd"
- iPad: "-ipad"
- iPad HD: "-ipadhd"
- Mac: ""
- Mac HD: "-machd"
```

This indicates now by default cocos2d support iPhone5. Why not working for me?

Comment: have u enabled RetinaSupport for your project?

Comment: yes..even I placed wide.png also..not working. Works great for iPad, iPadhd

Comment: which exact version is this, is it 2.1 rc1? And what exactly does "not working" mean? Expectation vs output?

Comment: cocos2d-iphone-2.1-rc1, in iPhone5 widehd.png is not used, instead hd.png is used. I have placed widehd.png in same folder.

Comment: What is the difference between iPhone5 and iPhone5 HD? Is the "-wide" suffix is working?

Comment: :) No. iPhone5 itself retina. So just widehd.png is enough and its not working...

Comment: Does your project have a [4-inch launch image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12397309/877465) set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cocos2d 3.0 its working with -iphone5hd extension

```
   imageName-iphone5hd.png  // For iPhone5 wide screen image
```

Answer (score 0):

CCFileUtils has the option to search resources in folders without using Suffix, and it's more clean than the suffix. To do that change the search mode from suffix to directory by using the following code:

```
CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
[sharedFileUtils setSearchMode:kCCFileUtilsSearchDirectoryMode];
```

Then, create at least one of the following folders:

```
resources-iphone5hd (for iPhone 5 retina resources )
resources-iphone5 (for iPhone 5 non-retina resources )
resources-iphonehd (for iPhone retina resources )
resources-iphone (for iPhone non-retina resources )
resources-ipadhd (for iPad retina resources )
resources-ipad (for iPad non-retina resources )
resources-mac (for OS X resources)
resources-machd (for OS X retina resources. N/A yet)
```