# Iphone 5 support

Tags: iphone, app-store

Today I tried uploading an update for an older iPhone app to the app store but was denied because it did not support the new iPhone 5 screen size. Do I have to rebuild the whole app to show on the 4 inch display or can I just compile it with the older 3.5 inch screens and it will do what other older apps do with centering it with black bars on top and bottom.

Comment: The part with the black bars is how your app appears currently. And that's no longer allowed. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution

Comment: It depends if you want to rebuild it to support newer versions of iOS or whether your simply want to update the app for users who are using the older versions of iOS

Comment: black bars is not an option now. You'll need to add a 4 inch launch image, and ensure all your views work well on the iPhone5 screen size. Its not too complicated to do this, provided you dont have a very complicated/dynamic UI with hardcoded frame values.

Answer (score 1):

You do have to rebuild the app, with a launch image sized for a 5 inch screen. That is what tells the system that the app runs on a 5 inch screen.

(You can *not* do what older apps do and show with the black bars. Your app *was* doing that already. But now you are submitting an update, and it is forbidden to do that without running at full size on the iPhone 5.)

Now, when your app *launches* on a 5 inch screen, it might not look very good without some good autoresizing or autolayout. But that's another issue. You will be able to tell that pretty quickly just by looking (in the iPhone 5 Simulator).