# How to set the Camera screen size in Retina 4?

Tags: camera, iphone-5

I've made the simple camera app in iPhone. In iPhone 4, it works well with the proper camera screen size, but in iPhone5 it appear the black bar between the camera screen and the bottom bar.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]))
{
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                                                [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tick"
                                                                                ofType:@"aiff"]],
                                     &_tickSound);

    self.imgPickController = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.imgPickController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.imgPickController.delegate = self;
    self.imgPickController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    posCaptDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    nCountSec = 0;
    self.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    [self initCamera];

}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is your app iPhone 5 optimised?.It could be a reason. if your app is not iPhone 5 optimised,

[This will help to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution?rq=1)

anyway you will have to do it. Now apps are not allowed to submit without iPhone 5 support .