# Displaying wrong height in 4-inch iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, ios-simulator

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 and my storyboard looks like this ,
[image: Storyboard]

When I run the app in any other hardware configuration (All sizes, iPhones and iPads) it works perfectly except the 4-inch retina. It cuts off at the top and at the bottom.
[image: Running the app on the simulator]

When i press home on the simulator the home-screen and the rest looks normal
[image: Home screen]

I'm completely baffled by what can cause this and i don't have an actual device with that size to test on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution ?

Comment: But it shouldn't cut the top and bottom off like that? I mean normally it would just extend the view area? Not just centre the display

Comment: have you made your app "ready for retina 5" by including the "Default-568h@2x.png"? else -> read tutorial ;)

Comment: Meant iPhone 5 / Retina 4-inch

Comment: It works, issue is fixed now by adding the retina launch image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone with this problem in xcode 5 (with your Default-568h@2x.png already included) may want to try creating an Asset collection - it fixed it for me (it also fixed a problem I had of icons and launch images not updating in the simulator)!

Comment: I have those weird black strip on top and bottom, unfortunately I cannot use an Asset collection since I need to have localized images :(